# How to colour the list-style-type auto-generated numbers?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm using the following list:

```
<ol id="footnotes">
    <a name="footnote1"><li></a>This is the first footnote...</li>
    <a name="footnote2"><li></a>This is the second footnote...</li>
</ol>
```

With the following .css:

```
#footnotes {list-style-type: decimal;
            list-style-color: #f90;
            }

#footnotes li
           {color: #000;
            }

#footnotes a li,
#footnotes li a
           {color: #f90;
            }
```

The aim is to have the li/footer text itself black (`#000`), and the number styled to orange (`#f90`).

I've tried using the `list-style-color` property but this does nothing except upset the Web developer toolbar (in FF3.0.8/Ubuntu 8.04), Midori similarly doesn't display the number in orange (I thought I'd try it in the Webkit engine, just in case...).

Any ideas?

Edited the HTML (since I remembered that the  tag doesn't necessarily need to enclose anything to function as an anchor):

```
<ol id="footnotes">
    <li><a name="footnote1"></a>This is the first footnote...</li>
    <li><a name="footnote2"></a>This is the second footnote...</li>
</ol>
```

In response to those that suggest using a `<span>` inside the `<li>`...yeah. That occurred, though I thank you for the suggestions and the time taken, but I was looking (li'l standardista that I am... ;) ) for a more...semantic option.

As it is, I think I'll probably use that approach. Though I accepted a different, Pete Michaud's, answer due to its sheer informative nature. Thanks!

Comment: Also instead of <a name="footn...> you should use <li id='footnote1'> less markup and <a name> isn't valid HTML5 code at the moment either.

Comment: Looking back at this question there are so many things wrong with my posted html, but changing it to be correct, now, feels like I'm cheating those who answered.

Comment: please pic Mårten Björk ans as correct ans.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, the kicker is that the numbers are technically generated inside the `<li>`, so anything you do to the `<li>` will affect the number. From the spec:

> "Most block-level elements in CSS generate one principal block box. 
>   In this section, we discuss two CSS mechanisms that cause an element 
>   to generate two boxes: one principal block box (for the element's 
>   content) and one separate marker box (for decoration such as a 
>   bullet, image, or number)."

Notice that both the marker box and the principal box belong to the 
same element - in this case, the list item.  Accordingly, we should 
expect all `<li>` styling to apply to both the marker and the content. 
This is also not surprising if you think about it as though the list 
item itself is generating the numbering content (which effectively it 
is doing in CSS terms).  This is confirmed later on when the spec 
continues:

> "The list properties allow basic visual formatting of lists. As with 
>   more general markers, a element with 'display: list-item' generates a 
>   principal box for the element's content and an optional marker box. 
>   The other list properties allow authors to specify the marker type 
>   (image, glyph, or number) and its position with respect to the 
>   principal box (outside it or within it before content). They do not 
>   allow authors to specify distinct style (colors, fonts, alignment, 
>   etc.) for the list marker or adjust its position with respect to the 
>   principal box."

So because the marker belongs to the list, it is affected by the `<li>` styling and isn't adjustable directly.  The only way to achieve a different styling for the marker is to insert a `<span>` inside the list item, and style the span with the properties you want to be different from the marker.

Comment: A lot of good points in this answer. However, you are wrong in saying: "The only way to achieve a different styling for the marker is to insert a `<span>` inside the list item, and style the span with the properties you want to be different from the marker." For an `<ol>`, for example, the key is using CSS generated content to create and insert the counter numbers after removing the default numbering from the list (see my answer).

Comment: `li::marker` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 51):

There is a way in CSS3, using the [Generated and Replaced Content Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/). With this technique you don't have do add any extra mark-up to your HTML. Something like this should do the trick:

```
ol li {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-increment: list;
    position: relative;
}

ol li:after {
    content: counter(list) ".";
    position: absolute;
    left: -2.5em;
    width: 2em;
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Good solution! But I found that using `:after`, the number would align with the last line in case the `li` contains multiple lines of text. Using `:before` instead fixes this. You could explicitly set `top: 0` as well. Apparently this solution works in all browsers [except IE7-](http://caniuse.com/css-counters), but that's good enough for me. :)

Comment: On a side note, [CSS2.1 already implemented generated content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html).

Answer (score 32):

This should work:

```
<ol id="footnotes">
    <li><span>This is the first footnote...</span></li>
    <li><span>This is the second footnote...</span></li>
</ol>

#footnotes li { color: #f90; }
#footnotes li span { color: #000; }
```

Comment: The question explicitly states solution must not be span based! Your question is not acceptable.

Answer (score 8):

This simple CSS3 solution works in most browsers (IE8 and up):

```css
ul {
    padding-left: 14px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li:before {
    color: #f90;
    content: "•";
    position: relative; 
    left: -7px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: -7px;
}
```

You may have to adjust the `padding` and `margin` values depending on your situation.

Comment: Be aware that this is not what the OP asked ("ol" instead of "ul" element)

Comment: While it is true that it was not what OP asked, its first result in google search, which is most likely because OP title does not state ol, but just list-style-type. Proper CSS3 ul QA, can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/how-to-set-the-color-of-bullets-in-ul-li-lists-via-css-without-using-images-or

Answer (score 6):

I recently had a similar problem and found an article, [Styling ordered list numbers](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/), that describes a smart way of achieving styling of the list markers **without using additional tags**. The article basically says that for an ordered list:

> The key is using CSS generated content to create and insert the
>   counter numbers after removing the default numbering from the list.

For more details please see the article.

Comment: It would have been helpful to give a brief description of the process involved, rather than just a "see here" link.

Answer (score 4):

These days you can just use `::marker`;

Example:

```
li::marker {
  color: #f90;
}
```

More here, including the browser compat table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker#Browser_compatibility

Comment: This should nowadays definitely be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
<head>
  <style>
    #footnotes li { color: #f90; }
    #footnotes li a { color: #000; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ol id="footnotes">
    <li><a name="footnote1">This is the first footnote...</a></li>
    <li><a name="footnote2">This is the second footnote...</a></li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Combining some of the other answers, which I found to be incomplete, I find this most complete. It considers **sub style-types** for different levels in the hierarchy and considers that an li may be more than one line (*:after* places at bottom line, so we use *:before*).

Note customizing of side character as well: `1. 1)`.Tested in Chrome.

```
ol { counter-reset:li; }
ol li {
    list-style-type:none;
    counter-increment:li;
    position:relative;
}
ol li:before {
    content:counter(li) ")";
    position:absolute;
    left: -2.6em;
    width: 2em;
    text-align: right;
    color: #f00;
}
ol ol li:before { content:counter(li,lower-alpha) ")"; }
ol ol ol li:before { content:counter(li,lower-roman) "."; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use "outside" list-style attribute.
[See here](http://www.echoecho.com/csslists.htm)

Comment: I could; but to what end? And in what way would using `list-style-position: outside;` (which is the *default* `list-style-position` anyway) help colour the number differently than the content of the `li`?