# Red dot similar to "li" element in HTML

Tags: html, css, layout

I have HTML code like this:

```
<tr>    
  <td align="left" valign="bottom"  class="leftfooter"><a href="#">Customer Support</a> <a href="#" class="footerlink">About</a></td>
</tr>
```

How can I place one small red dot in front of the entire text?  Kind of like

but red and smaller.

**Edit**

Just to clarify, I didn't write this HTML.  I just copied and pasted it to show what I'm working with.  I realize that I should use an unordered list to do this same task instead of a table structure for this purpose for semantic reasons.  If I can, I will see if I can modify this piece of the code to a more suitable one in the customer's codebase.

Comment: -1 I see a non-semantic usage of tables.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I don't think that should be a criterion for downvoting a question. I am upvoting it...

Comment: is this realy worth a -1 ??? You don't know why he has to do this. Maybe he works on a sharepoint project :) you should just downvote questions when they are badly asked or if they make no sense, but this one does.

Comment: @Sayem, @meo, personally I don't think 'sympathy' should be a criterion for up-voting a question.

Comment: @meo, I actually am working on a sharepoint project..how did you know?

Comment: @David: I didn't upvote it because I tried to show sympathy. I upvoted it because I also don't know how to place a red dot :-) .

Comment: I will remove my downvote when @Sev edits the question to say that he did not write the non-semantic html and understands why it is a bad idea. Each user may vote as he or she pleases, and I prefer to down vote poor usage of semantics. When people prove that they have some semblance of understanding of what not to do, I gladly remove my downvotes.

Comment: @Sev its not hard to tell, sharepoint generate the worst FrontEnd Code i ever saw, full of tables and shit. But its a MS product so its a surprise for no one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hadn't noticed that you were using `table` elements, at first, so I'll preface my existing answer with the **strong suggestion** to use an actual `ul`, or `ol`, element. Which conveys some form of meaning of the contents therein. **Please** consider screen-readers, or users with devices that access the data non-visually.

Pretty easily:

#### html:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Some text</span></li>
    <li><span>more stuff</span></li>
</ul>
```

#### css:

```
ul {
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    list-style-type: disc;
}

li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    color: #f00;
}

li > span {
    color: #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/axQg7/1/).

#### Explanation:

The reason for the `span` within the `li` elements is that the text-color of the 'bullet' (`list-style-type: disc;`) cannot be changed independently of the text of the `li` itself. Using the `span` allows the text contained within to be of a different `color` to the 'bullet.'

This is partially related to my own question: [How to colour the `list-style-type` of aut-generated numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725741/how-to-colour-the-list-style-type-auto-generated-numbers).

---

However to answer the question as asked:

Using the following image:
[image]

The following css will work:

```
td {
    background: #fff url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5lQ4.gif) 0 50% no-repeat;
    padding-left: 14px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/axQg7/2/).

I leave it entirely to you to find an actual red bullet image.

Comment: You can also change the `font-size` property on the `li` to change the size of the bullet.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it the simplest way possible, you can use an HTML entity Bullet:  •

`&bull;` (not valid xhtml)

or

`&#8226;`

You can wrap it in a span to color it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Web Design Library's [How to Assign Custom List Bullets with CSS](http://www.webdesign.org/html-and-css/tutorials/how-to-assign-custom-list-bullets-with-css.12817.html) has a tutorial which uses the [`list-style-image`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/list-style-image) CSS property to specify an image.