# Enter key triggers wrong submit button

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I am working on an mvc application.  Two tables each have their individual submit button.  Table1 has default submit on enter key.  How do I change the submit button based on textbox focus?

```
<table>
...<td align="left"><%= Html.TextBox("name")%></td>
...<input id="nameSubmit" name="NameSubmit" type="submit" value="Search"/>
</table>
<table>
...<td align="left"><%= Html.TextBox("idNum")%></td>
...<input id="idSubmit" name="IdSubmit" type="submit" value="Search"/>
</table>
```

I tried using the panel, but "the DefaultButton of 'Panel1' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl".

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the default submit button on an HTML form determined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925334/how-is-the-default-submit-button-on-an-html-form-determined)

Comment: @zzzzBov Let us consider the tooltip on the downvote button: "This question is unclear or not useful". Give the OP a break. :P

Comment: @djacobson, I've had this come up before; And you can read [my policy on misused table elements here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009718/red-dot-similar-to-li-element-in-html).

Comment: @zzzzBov - I just wanted to paint a picture of what I am working with.  You consider it worthy of a down vote, acknowledged.

Comment: @zzzzBov I appreciate the elucidation of your policy. My disagreement with it remains. In the OP's words, acknowledged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wrap each of the submits in `<form>` tags that should help determine which submit was clicked as such:

```
<table>
    <form id="form1">
        <td align="left"><input id="name" /></td>
        <input id="nameSubmit" name="NameSubmit" type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>       
</table>
<table>
    <form id="form2">
        <td align="left"><input id="number" /></td>
        <input id="idSubmit" name="IdSubmit" type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
</table>
```

This would make any Enter presses while the textbox was focused submit to the corresponding form.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rY8Xf/) is a demo of this working, I hope that it helps you out.

Comment: What I was looking for actually... this tackled the problem at hand. Thanks!

Comment: this is not working for me it submits with ctl word which breaks .search.aspx?ctl00%24brand=asd