# How to set Bullet colors in UL/LI html lists via CSS without using any images or span tags

Tags: css, layout, colors, html-lists

Imagine a simple unsorted list with some `<li>` items. Now, I have defined the bullets to be square shaped via  `list-style:square;` However, if I set the color of the `<li>` items with `color: #F00;` then *everything* becomes red!

While I only want to set the color of the square bullets. Is there an **elegant way** to define the color of the bullets in CSS...

## *...without using any sprite images nor span tags!*

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li{
   list-style:square;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done elegantly (but I'm no CSS expert). If you don't get a "right" answer, you could consider using list-style-image and setting it to an image of a colored bullet.

Comment: Is (was) there any reason why not to use a <span>? For me this seems to be the only elegant and timeless way of doing this. It works perfectly cross browser even the demon child called IE supports it. It also grands a lot of control between the text and bullet like size.

Answer (score 1073, accepted):

The most common way to do this is something along these lines:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 1em; 
  text-indent: -.7em;
}

li::before {
  content: "• ";
  color: red; /* or whatever color you prefer */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
</ul>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/ytH5P/

Will work in all browsers, including IE from version 8 and up.

Comment: in contrast to the other *`impossible cannot be done`* answers, you have solved this as a *`very sossible`* answer! Clever, creative, short... timelessy ELEGANT! thanks

Comment: being a nitwit, I would remove the extra space in `"• "` ==> `"•"` and add this line below it:  `padding-right:7px;` bit more controll there :)  the rest is awesome and works everywhere. PS what does the `:before` mean/do here?

Comment: instead of `"• "` also possible: `content: "4"; font-family:"Webdings";` which will result in a nice `>`  or for a nice ■  `content: "■"; font-family:"Arial Black";`

Comment: @Sam #1: :) @Sam #2: You're right about the space, I'm just lazy :$ Better set the padding in ems though, otherwise it'll break when font-size changes (either because you changed the CSS or because the end user adjusted it) @Sam #3: I wouldn't trust dingbat fonts in web pages, some browsers used to choke in the past (haven't tried it recently). Better just use the unicode character.

Comment: Oh, and as for what `:before` does: It lets you dynamically insert (presentational) content inside an element, **before** its "real" content. More: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content (I pasted the CSS2 spec to show you it's not even CSS3)

Comment: another alternative to `"•"` is `"\002022"`

Comment: use **content: "● "** for the disc as exactly appear in list-style-type:disc

Comment: @Sam "font-family:"Webdings";" is a terrible idea; you can't assume every user will have that font installed on their system (I don't, and I'm pretty sure it's not that common, especially on mobile devices).

Comment: @LeaVerou This solution negates the effect of `list-style-position: outside;`, and multiple-line `li` don't look well . To solve it, simply use `margin-left: -15px; /*or whatever value works for you*/`

Comment: Hmm, you could set `display: inline-block` and `width: 0.7em` for `li:before` and only have `text-indent: -0.7em` for `li`. That way, the left edge of the text will be precisely aligned even in multi-line list items.

Comment: Also, by adding one of these spaces: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)#Spaces_in_Unicode into the li:before content CSS, such as an Em space, you can get an indent between the list icon and the list body.

Comment: You can also use almost all unicode characters like ★✱✿♥✎✔☞ etc. If the CSS file has the UTF-8 encoding, these characters can be just pasted there, without any escaping.

Comment: Recommend adding "font-weight:bold;" or even better "font-weight:900" to li:before to enlarge the disc in Lea's solution. Also, krish answer looks great if I copy straight from here to Chrome's console. However my html editor does not know "content: "● "" and turns it into question mark (?)

Comment: I use something similar to the answer to achieve a `list-style-position: outside` effect. I give the `:after` selector a value of `position: absolute` and `margin-left: -0.8em` (instead of a `padding-right' declaration).

Comment: This might have been a good answer in 2011 but nowadays this does not work properly cross browser or not at all.

Comment: @MennoGouw It's 2014 here, and this solution works perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: @walterroman so it would work perfectly for about 20% of the people. If you are ook with that then use it.

Comment: Just nice to read "including IE".

Comment: original bullet with &nbsp; in css: li:before {content: "\25cf\00a0";} for right aligning: li{padding-left: 1em;text-indent: -1em;} tested with all major browsers

Comment: To enlarge the circle I added the following to `li:before{font-size: 200%;line-height: 50%;vertical-align: sub;}`

Comment: @MennoGuow What exactly do you mean? I just tested on the latest Firefox, Chrome, and Opera and it works fine... Not sure if you were referring to someone's comment.

Comment: It's preferable to provide in unicode, as `"\2022"`. Theoretically, it is "\002022", but you can leave out the leading 0s. Also ref: [Placing Unicode character in CSS content value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10393517/235415)

Comment: This solution depends on how the browser renders the dot. If you replace the character by another one, the alignment does not fit anymore: see http://jsfiddle.net/ytH5P/5024/

Comment: If you want text-shadow to simulate outlines, like in my case, you have to add the shadow width to the padding. Also I prefer pixels to em for this special case: http://jsfiddle.net/mj3evc5y/2/

Comment: Why doesn't this work in IE???

Comment: Why isn't this a simple css property?  So weird.

Comment: What if I want to preserve numeric index? No way. This is a hack to me. The best solution is the one by Benito (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13590719/214517) , which simply styles `li` then wraps and styles its content separately.

Comment: I am unable to apply ANY color when using "\2022", this is in the chrome browser. But when I use `● ` is gets colored correctly. Did some spec change?

Comment: I ran with li {text-indent: -.7em;}

Answer (score 92):

browsing sometime ago, found this site, have you tried this alternative?

```
li{
    list-style-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAE0lEQVQIW2NkYGD4D8RwwEi6AACaVAQBULo4sgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
}
```

sounds hard, but you can make your own png image/pattern **[here](http://www.patternify.com/)**, then copy/paste your code and customize your bullets =) stills elegant?

EDIT:

following the idea of @lea-verou on the other answer and applying this philosophy of outside sources enhancement I've come to this other solution:

1. embed in your head the stylesheet of the Webfont icons Library, in this case Font Awesome:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

2. take a code from FontAwesome [cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) (or any other webfont icons).

> ```
> i.e.:
> fa-angle-right [&#xf105;]
> ```

and use the last part of f... followed by a number like this, with the `font-family` too:

```
li:before {
    content: "\f105";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: red; /* or whatever color you prefer */
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

and that's it! now you have custom bullet tips too =)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytH5P/5721/)

Comment: I needed a solution for ie7 (of course, does not supports the :before selector).

Comment: So sorry to say that base64 images don't work in IE7 either... otherwise it would be the best solution...

Comment: Upvote for *`out of the box`* thinking

Comment: Screw IE7. It's a really old browser by now. This solution rocks! Anyway, if you really want to support IE7 you can just copy and paste the Base64 code into a modern browser address bar, then save the image as a PNG file using Ctrl+S (or Cmd+S in Mac) and use the actual PNG file instead of the Base64 encoded string

Comment: Patternify is *awesome*

Comment: So much cleaner than accepted answer. I hate having to do negative indents and margins. Makes maintenance a nightmare.

Answer (score 62):

I simply solve this problem like this, which should work in all browsers:

```css
ul li {
  color: red
}

ul li span {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Foo</span></li>
  <li><span>Bar</span></li>
  <li><span>Bat</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oops, sorry. Overread that an answer was wanted WITHOUT span  :-(

Comment: Also he wanted the bullet of another color, not the text.

Comment: All good, man. Helped in my first try. This almost never happens, you know how things go. Thanks for the answer. BTW, why not span?

Comment: the only non-bicycle solution here

Answer (score 60):

The current spec of the [CSS 3 Lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#marker-pseudoelement) module does specify the [`::marker`
pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#marker-pseudo-element) which would do exactly what you want; FF has been tested
to not support `::marker` and I doubt that either Safari or Opera has it.
IE, of course, does not support it.

So right now, the only way to do this is to use an image with `list-style-image`.

I guess you could wrap the contents of an `li` with a `span` and then you could set the color of each, but that seems a little hackish to me.

Comment: +1 for this: `"IE, of course, does not support it."` :)

Comment: As of 15th Dec 2016 no major browser supports :marker, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-marker-pseudo

Comment: @Kredns - nowadays referred to as an "Edge case".

Comment: What a shame! Until 2018 none of the major browser support this yet!

Comment: Firefox and Safari now do support `::marker` pseudo elements.

Comment: This answer is slightly outdated. [`::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker#Browser_compatibility) is now supported in all modern browsers except Opera.

Comment: @Alex please update your answer now that it is supported everywhere.

Answer (score 51):

One way to do it is using `li:before` with `content: ""` and styling it as `inline-block` element.

*Here is a working code snippet:*

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none; /* no default bullets */
}

ul li { 
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

ul li:before { /* the custom styled bullets */
  background-color: #14CCBB;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Swollen joints</li>
  <li>Pain in hands and knees</li>
  <li>Redness around joints</li>
  <li>Constant fatigue</li>
  <li>Morning stiffness in joints</li>
  <li>High fevers</li>
  <li>Rheumatoid nodules, which develop around joints</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So much easier than using content ". " or "\2022" as you don't need to worry about positioning of the bullet next to the text

Comment: Might be better to use `ul li:before { ... }` so that it doesn't mess with `ol` lists as well

Comment: @yeahlad good point! I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 25):

Yet, another solution is to use a `:before` pseudo element with a `border-radius: 50%`. This will work in all browsers, including IE 8 and up.

Using the `em` unit allows responsiveness to font size changes. You can test this, by resizing your jsFiddle window.

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 3vw;
}

ul li:before {
    content: "";
    line-height: 1em;
    width: .5em;
    height: .5em;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin: .25em .25em 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HS82t/224/)

You can even play with the `box-shadow` to create some nice shadows, something that will not look nice with the `content: "• "` solution.

Comment: This worked perfect. I had to adjust the margin to be: `margin: 0.5em 0.25em 0 0`, but otherwise this was perfect

Answer (score 20):

I tried this and things got weird for me. (css stopped working after the `:after {content: "";}` part of this tutorial. I found you can color the bullets by just using `color:#ddd;` on the `li` item itself.

Here's an **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/bGKYJ/2/)**.

```
li{
    color:#ff0000;    
    list-style:square;                
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#00ff00;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: It is not. This also colors the text in the `li`, obviously.

Comment: @oarfish not actually, the text in li are wrapped with another tag, in case i used span.

Comment: I wrapped the inside li text with a span a this works wonders. Best answer!

Answer (score 17):

I use jQuery for this:

```
jQuery('li').wrapInner('<span class="li_content" />');
```

& with some CSS:

```
li { color: red; }
li span.li_content { color: black; }
```

maybe overkill, but handy if you're coding for a CMS and you don't want to ask your editors to put an extra span in every list-items.

Comment: Aside from the jQuery bit this is the most cross-browser and (for me) cross-email-client compatible solution I have found.

Comment: Email compatible jQuery??

Comment: Keep in mind, that if no javascript is available, the base-color will become your fancy bullets color.

Comment: I styled the list normally and then if the js ran I updated the styling. That prevents the bullet color from being used for the list if js hasn't executed. Like: jQuery('ol').addClass('ol-wrapper').find('li').wrapInner('<span class="li-content" />');

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend giving the `LI` a `background-image` and `padding-left`. The `list-style-image` attribute is flakey in cross-browser environments, and adding an extra element, such as a span, is unneccessary.  So your code would end up looking something like this:

```
li {
  background:url(../images/bullet.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The easiest thing you can do is wrap the contents of the `<li>` in a `<span>` or equivalent then you can set the color independently.

Alternatively, you could make an image with the bullet color you want and set it with the `list-style-image` property.

Comment: Works also if you would like to make numbers on an OL bold.

Comment: This is a no brainer for compatibility.

Comment: Yeah this is what I use for older IE compatibility. We're still supporting IE7 for legacy reasons of a very large company. The li::before method in the accepted answer above does not work in IE7 as it doesn't support ::before.

Answer (score 8):

A variation of [Lea Verou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90826/lea-verou) solution with perfect indentation in multi-line entries could be something like this:

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li{
    padding-left: 1.5em; 
}

li:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "•";
    color: red;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution is good if your first element in a li has display:block, as a p element

Answer (score 6):

I know it's a bit of a late answer for this post, but for reference...

CSS

```
ul {
    color: red;
}

li {
    color: black;
}
```

The bullet colour is defined on the ul tag and then we switch the li colour back.

Comment: Not working in Chrome. Sadly.

Comment: Also not in Firefox 24.

Comment: Works in Firefox 25 and the most recent version of Chrome

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but changing `li {` to `ul li * {` does. Tested in Chrome v51 and Firefox v47.0

Comment: This does not work. Ferry, it likely worked for you because your text was wrapped in another element, such as ```<a>``` or ```<span>```.

Answer (score 6):

I am adding my solution to this problem.

I don't want to use image and validator will punish you for using negative values in CSS, so I go this way:

```
ul          { list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; }

li          { padding-left:0.75em; position:relative; }

li:before       { content:"•"; color:#e60000; position:absolute; left:0em; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking Lea's demo, here's a different way of making unordered lists, with borders: http://jsfiddle.net/vX4K8/7/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <ul>
        <li>Son</li>
        <li>Of</li>
            <ul>
            <li>Foo</li>
            <li>Bar</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
}

ul:first-child {
   padding: 0;
}

li {
    line-height: 180%;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #CCC;
    margin-left: 14px;
    text-indent: -14px;
}

li:last-child {
    border: none;
}

li:before {
    content: "";
    border-left: 4px solid #CCC;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: @user2188875 Very interesting twist! Thanks for elevating the question and so creatively adding new meaning to the answer. Indeed this way lists could be stylised very maturely! Is this compatible in email html templates too? say one would use this for html mails and send them. Would the receiving party (mac/win7/win10/android/etc) see and read the html properly??

Answer (score 3):

Lea Verous solution is good but i wanted more control over the position of the bullets so this is my approach:

```
.entry ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /* hide overflow in the case of floating elements around ... */
    overflow: hidden;
}
.entry li { 
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 24px;
}
.entry li:before {
    /* with absolute position you can move this around or make it bigger without getting unwanted scrollbars */
    position: absolute;
    content: "• ";
    color: #E94E24;
    font-size: 30px;
    left: 0;
    /* use fonts like "arial" or use "sans-serif" to make the dot perfect round */ 
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score -17):

This will do it..

```
li{
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This will only affect the text content in the li element. Not the list style.