# Is there any way to change color of the list-style circle using css

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to define the Color of Bullets in UL/LI Lists via CSS,  WITHOUT using any image bullets or any span tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/how-to-define-the-color-of-bullets-in-ul-li-lists-via-css-without-using-any-im)

how can change the color of the list-style circle using css

my css is:

```
 ul{
   list-style:circle;
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this.

```
    <ul>
    <li><span>text</span></li>
    </ul>

    ul li {
       list-style:circle;
       color:blue;
     }

    ul li span {
       color:#000;
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is:

```
ul {
    list-style:circle;
    color:blue;
}
```

For other font color additionally do this:

```
ul span {
    color:black;
}
```

and html:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>This is a black line</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: now the text color also become blue ,i don't want that,i want only the circle color needs to change..

Comment: thats why I edited the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the topic Soufiane Hassou mentioned is the best way to go, but if you don't mind using spans in the li, you could use:

```
ul
    {
        list-style: circle;
        color: #FF0000;
    }

    ul span
    {
        color: Black;
    }
```

Where the HTML is:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Test-text</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This will mark the bullet red, but the text Black.