# Use FontAwesome or Glyphicons with css :before

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Is there any way to embed HTML in the css `content:` element when using a `:before` pseudo-element?

I want to use a Font Awesome (or Glyphicon) in a use case like this:

```
    h1:before {
        content: "X";
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        color: @orangeLight;
    }
```

Where `X` is something like `<i class="icon-cut"></i>`.

I can, of course do this manually in HTML, but I really want to use `:before` in this case.

Similarly, is there any way to use `<i>` as a list bullet?  This works, but doesn't behave correctly for multi-line bullet items:

```
<ul class="icons">
  <li><i class="icon-ok"></i> Lists</li>
  <li><i class="icon-ok"></i> Buttons</li>
  <li><i class="icon-ok"></i> Button groups</li>
  <li><i class="icon-ok"></i> Navigation</li>
  <li><i class="icon-ok"></i> Prepended form inputs</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Since `:before` is a pseudo element, you can't have `html` content, only `text`.

Comment: Hi tig, just checking if my answer was sufficient. Hope it helped. Thanks!

Comment: You really should accept wylander's answer. It totally does what I need, which seems to be what you wanted, too!

Answer (score 161, accepted):

What you are describing is actually what FontAwesome is doing already. They apply the FontAwesome font-family to the `::before` pseudo element of any element that has a class that starts with "icon-".

```
[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

Then they use the pseudo element `::before` to place the icon in the element with the class. I just went to http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/ and inspected the code to find this:

```
.icon-cut:before {
  content: "\f0c4";
}
```

So if you are looking to add the icon again, you could use the `::after` element to achieve this. Or for your second part of your question, you could use the `::after` pseudo element to insert the bullet character to look like a list item. Then use absolute positioning to place it to the left, or something similar.

```
i:after{ content: '\2022';}
```

Comment: Here you can find all content icon codes `"\xxxx";` : http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

Comment: @miromarchi That's a nice list all in one spot! Thanks for sharing! Also, if you go to the font awesome website that lists the icons (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) and click on one of the icons, the page has the Unicode towards the top, which is the same number used in the content property.

Comment: Is it possible to use unicode values of icons?    \2022  ---> what format is this?

Comment: @ratata The \2022 format I believe is the hexadecimal representation of unicode. See this question and answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393462/placing-unicode-character-in-css-content-value

Comment: if you're using the *SVG-with-JS* approach: read my answer on how that works .. or @ https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements#with-svg-js

Comment: Had to fumble around a bit to figure out how to actually put this into practice... what I ended up with have a "callout" css class: https://gist.github.com/AlecBenzer/7d894a03e493a4b7908b38f6684d95cd

Answer (score 4):

@keithwyland answer is great. Here's a SCSS mixin:

```
@mixin font-awesome($content){
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    content: $content;
}
```

Usage:

```
@include font-awesome("\f054");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your list items there is a little CSS you can use to achieve the desired effect.

```
ul.icons li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: -20px; // for example
}
ul.icons li i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

I have tested this in Safari on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

This approach should be avoided. The default value for `vertical-align` is `baseline`. Changing the font-family of only the pseudo element will result in elements with differing fonts. Different fonts can have different font metrics and different baselines. In order for different baselines to align, the overall height of the element would have to increase. [See this effect in action](http://codepen.io/Keyamoon/pen/MYxpxQ).

It is always better to have one element per font icon.

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer (as of 2019 JULY 29)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11919684/3022387) is only still valid if you have not started using the more recent **SVG-with-JS** approach of FontAwesome. In which case you need to follow the instructions on their [CSS Pseudo-Elements HowTo](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements#with-svg-js).
Basically there are three things to watch out for:

- place the data-attribute on the SCRIPT-Tag
  "data-search-pseudo-elements" loading the fontawesome.min.js
- make the pseudo-element itself have display:none
- proper font-family & font-weight combination for the
  icon you need: "Font Awesome 5 Free" and 300 (fal/light), 400 (far/regular) or 900 (fas/solid)

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest way to do what you are trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZEDHT/

```
<style>
 ul {
   list-style-type: none;
 }
</style>

<ul class="icons">
 <li><i class="fa fa-bomb"></i> Lists</li>
 <li><i class="fa fa-bomb"></i> Buttons</li>
 <li><i class="fa fa-bomb"></i> Button groups</li>
 <li><i class="fa fa-bomb"></i> Navigation</li>
 <li><i class="fa fa-bomb"></i> Prepended form inputs</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Re: using icon in `:before` –
recent Font Awesome builds include the `.fa-icon()` mixin for SASS and LESS. This will automatically include the `font-family` as well as some rendering tweaks (e.g. `-webkit-font-smoothing`). Thus you can do, e.g.:

```
// Add "?" icon to header.
h1:before {
    .fa-icon();
    content: "\f059";
}
```

Comment: Just a brief reminder that font awesome also provides variables to use as content so that one can also use:   
    .pseudo-class:before {
      @include fa-icon();
      content: $fa-var-phone-square;
  }

Answer (score -14):

```
<ul class="icons-ul">
<li><i class="icon-play-sign"></i> <a>option</a></li>
<li><i class="icon-play-sign"></i> <a>option</a></li>
<li><i class="icon-play-sign"></i> <a>option</a></li>
<li><i class="icon-play-sign"></i> <a>option</a></li>
<li><i class="icon-play-sign"></i> <a>option</a></li>
</ul>
```

All the font awesome icons comes default with Bootstrap.

Comment: since when? bootstrap comes with glyphicons, not with fontawesome.