# How to handle scroll for various mobile devices using media queries for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, media-queries, microsoft-edge

I have a scenario where on a certain page there is a form with two radio buttons and two normal buttons "submit" and "cancel".

In normal Viewport it works fine, but when it comes to mobile devices there are some devices and browsers, like [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge), where these <kbd>Submit</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> buttons are not visible. When I try to scroll down, it’s not working. As I had tested on BrowserStack for iOS and Android, there is this issue with some devices, so how can I fix this, making sure it will work for all devices and browsers?

I have given *padding-bottom* of 80 pixels using a [media query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries) of max-width 576 pixels where *md* is 576 pixels.

```css
@media (max-width: map-get($grid-breakpoints, md)) {
  .app-overlay{
    padding-bottom: 80px;
  }
}
```

Comment: @AbhishekK top-nav-height is 56px.
```
.app-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: $top-nav-height;
  left: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - #{$top-nav-height});
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: @AbhishekK note that SO requires code to be within the question, not on an external site. This is because SO is trying to build up a set of useful questions and answers for future readers, not just solve the issue for one user at a point in time, and external sites can easily disappear or change.

Comment: What is *map-get*? [From Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254520/sass-whats-the-difference-between-map-get-and-simple-variable)?

Comment: Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue. The code you provide can't be run.