# Quick one: putting <element> in ::before section

Tags: html, css

just wanted to make sure. 
Is there any chance I could be puttnig something like:

```
&::before{
content:"<span class='far fa-square'></span>"
```

I'd love for certain items to have some icons ::before but following the [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) from css-tricks there is no chance and I can only put it as an image or a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use FontAwesome or Glyphicons with css :before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875088/use-fontawesome-or-glyphicons-with-css-before)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the font-awesome docs. Don't hate me.

[Docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements)

The way to do it is to use the unicode.