# Unicode via CSS :before

Tags: html, css, unicode, encoding, icons

I am using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) on my webpage and I want to display an icon inside the `:before` pseudo element.

According to the [documentation/cheatsheet](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/), I have to type `&#xf066;` to get this font, but it isn't working. I believe that is normal because HTML entities aren't supported in `:before`.
So I googled a bit and found out, that if you want to display HTML entities in `:before`, you have to use the escaped hex reference.
So I was searching for the hex reference to `&#xf066;` but I found nothing. I believe that is because these are "private use" values, whatever that means.

Is there any way to get it working in `:before`?

Comment: Since the link is a 404, you may be talking about pseduo elements? Did you try adding `content: "";` in the CSS for your `:before` element?

Comment: pretty sure its this: http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/

Comment: Yep, sorry guys! Link is fixed now! @tsujp Actually, the icon should be displayed inside the pseudo element.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can't display HTML entities in `:before`. You can display Unicode characters represented by entities references in HTML, but you don't do it using the HTML entity syntax.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The escaped hex reference of `&#xf066;` is `\f066`.

```
content: "\f066";
```

Comment: Everyone please see the answer from super_ton, that you will need to declare font-family with FontAwesome. Otherwise you'll only get a special symbol and not the correct icon!

Comment: For anyone who is using CSS parsed in PHP, you'll need to double-escape the hex reference like this: content: "\\f066";

Comment: Note that if using Font Awesome 5, the font family has changed. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48004111/83542

Answer (score 160):

In CSS, FontAwesome unicode works only when the correct font family is declared (version 4 or less):

```
font-family: "FontAwesome";
content: "\f066";
```

Update - Version 5 has different names:

Free

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"
```

Pro

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"
```

Brands

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands"
```

See this related answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48004111/2575724

As per comment (BuddyZ) some more info here https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-desktop/setup/getting-started

Comment: I like how you added the font-family part because that is the key that made mine work

Comment: Note that if using Font Awesome 5, the font family has changed. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48004111/83542

Comment: only 
font-family: FontAwesome worked for me. not 
font-family: "FontAwesome"

Comment: Surprisingly, nothing worked for me except for what @Sameera said. Can confirm that, as of 10/23/19, only font-family: FontAwesome worked for me as well. I wanted to use [FA's arrow icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/arrow-right?style=regular). This was my code: `a:last-child:after {
          font-family: FontAwesome;
          content: '\f061';
        }`

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 11):

[Fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f066/index.htm) is a pretty good reference for this stuff. In your case, it's already in hex, so the hex value is `f066`. So you'd do:

```
content: "\f066";
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I didn't realize the icons were in hex for some reason. So I kept putting '#' in the string and it wouldn't work. Now it works.

Answer (score 3):

The code points used in icon font tricks are usually Private Use code points, which means that they have no generally defined meaning and should not be used in open information interchange, only by private agreement between interested parties. However, Private Use code points can be represented as any other Unicode value, e.g. in CSS using a notation like `\f066`, as others have answered. You can even enter the code point as such, if your document is UTF-8 encoded and you know how to type an arbitrary Unicode value by its number in your authoring environment (but of course it would normally be displayed using a symbol for an unknown character).

However, this is not the normal way of using icon fonts. Normally you use a CSS file provided with the font and use constructs like `<span class="icon-resize-small">foo</span>`. The CSS code will then take care of inserting the symbol at the start of the element, and you don’t need to know the code point number.

Answer (score 1):

At first link fontwaesome CSS file in your HTML file then create an after or before pseudo class like "font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f101";" then save. I hope this work good.

Answer (score 1):

Important thing - you have to add the font-weight (font-weight:900) to get it work.

Comment: Nice answer but it would be better to add some reason and explaining.