# how to add checkbox in select box using struts2

Tags: jsp, checkbox, struts2, checkboxlist

I'm trying to create check box list which appears in select tag. I've searched many article, I didn't get the proper output for that. Please help me out to solve this issue.

```
 <s:checkboxlist list = "%{cityList}" 
                 name = "cityNo" 
                   id = "cityNo" 
             cssClass = "margin-right margin-top required-field" 
             cssStyle = "width: 114px;height:30px"
            headerKey = "0" 
          headerValue = "City"   
              listKey = "id" 
            listValue = "cityName" 
              onfocus = "getcitywithCountry(false);" />
```

Comment: You should specify HOW it does not work. Which error do you get and so on...

Comment: Do you want to have a checkbox per option in select tag?

Comment: Missed the "in select tag" part... then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option

Comment: yes, Mr. Roman. just I want to have checkbox per option in select tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `s:checkboxlist` to implement the functionality that you need.

Download the following

```
http://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/raw/1.13/src/jquery.multiselect.min.js
http://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/raw/1.13/jquery.multiselect.css
```

and add them to your jsp. Then use a `s:select` element with `multiple` attribute set to `true`

```
<s:select id='your_id' multiple="true" name='your_name' key='key_from_properties_file' theme="xhtml" list='your_list' listKey='your_id' listValue='your_value' />
```

Comment: its not working in <s:select> tag. please provide me some ideas

Comment: @UmarMuktharKadherIbrahim What do you mean that it is not working, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I've added js and css in my jsp and I've add ("#cityNo").multiselect() in my ajax function. but it doesn't work. is there any other way to do that task please

Comment: @UmarMuktharKadherIbrahim Create a new question and post your code, I think that will be better.