# How can I make a checkbox inside a selectbox?

Tags: html

I would love to make a select box, which has checkboxes inside. Something like this:

```
<form>
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo"><input type="checkbox" name="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
    <option value="saab"><input type="checkbox" name="saab">Saab 95</option>
    <option value="mercedes"><input type="checkbox" name="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
    <option value="audi"><input type="checkbox" name="audi">Audi TT</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Is this possible? It is not for multiple selection. It means the selected value is independent from the checkboxes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Checkbox inside Select Option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option)

Comment: @Aʟᴀɢᴀʀᴏs no this is not a dublicate because I do not want multiselector checkboxes

Comment: But it's the same way of working

Comment: I tried the code from your suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/qq8qsago/

Answer (score 0):

check below link, it may usefull

[www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/)

Comment: Thank you, yes I found this, but it is for multiple selection. I need the checkbox independent from the selectbox