# how to add check box inside select tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to select multiple values inside a drop down using check boxes, I confused how to attain without changing TLD file. ie each option for the select will have the check box

[image: sample html]

sample code which iI work is below

```
 <form:select path="brandIds" id="brandDropdownSelectId" tabindex="31" multiple="true" size="4"  >
                            <option value="0">Select Brand</option>
                            <form:options items="${brandList}" itemValue="brandId"
                                itemLabel="brandName" checkbox="true"/>
                        </form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use external component like [Twitter Bootstrap Multi-select](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

Answer (score 0):

You can never use Checkbox inside a Select tag.
But, to solve this issue, we make use of *CSS+Javascript* to render the effect.

You define a empty select tag with a javascript function to alter the visibility of the checkboxes on click, and CSS plays the role of portraying the rendering in single effect.

This might help you:
[Adding checkboxes inside a Select Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547021/6820056)