# bootstrap multiselect get value with Angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to get the value of the selected options in my multiselect dropdown list.
But i do not get this done by `ngModel..`

Here the html:

```
 <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-3">
    <form class="btn-group" id="select-form">
        <select id="dropdown-list" multiple="multiple" [(ngModel)]="selectedObject"></select>
       <button type="reset" id="reset-button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and here the the for loop which append options to the select:

```
ngOnInit() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.checks.length; i++){
        var append = this.checks[i];
        $('#dropdown-list').append('<option>'+ append.name +'</option>');
    }
```

This because the `ngFor` is not working here.. but that's not my question in this case.

Can somebody help me to log the selected `options = [(ngModel)]="selectObject"`

Answer (score 6):

Multi-select does not seem to be supported yet, see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4427.

Here's a workaround (that does not use query selectors):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `{{title}}<p>
  <select multiple="multiple" (change)="change($event.target.options)">
    <option *ngFor="#item of items">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
  <p>{{selectedOptions | json}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "Angular 2 beta - multi select list";
  items = 'one two three'.split(' ');
  constructor() { console.clear(); }
  change(options) {
    this.selectedOptions = Array.apply(null,options)  // convert to real array
      .filter(option => option.selected)
      .map(option => option.value)
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a4OOwiwyVkGpQHIJkQTq?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: this is not working for me.. just like the ngFor for options is not working too. Ill post in next comment my code for better view

Comment: <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-3">
        <form class="btn-group" id="select-form">
            <select id="dropdown-list" multiple="multiple" (change)="onChange($event.target.options)"></select>
           <button type="reset" id="reset-button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <p>{{selectedOptions | json}}

Comment: onChange(options) {
         console.log('chekc');
         this.selectedOptions = Array.apply(null,options)
             .filter(option => option.selected)
             .map(option => option.value);

         console.log(this.selectedOptions);
     }

Comment: the onChange method is not triggered as you can see i checked it with a log

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer, the bootstrap library you are using probably adds/registers its own onchange event handler, which replaces the Angular one.  See if there is a way to add your own logic to their handler.

Comment: Hmm but in every other component it is working, you maybe know why the ngFor is not showing any results?

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer, I don't know.  Can you create a Plunker?

Comment: uhm i did not succeeded in that, but i think i see the problem. Because i set the change on the select but there is no change in that because it is in the dropdown menu of the multiselect.

Comment: All of this is working when i do not use the multiselect plugin.

Comment: did you manage to solve this with bootstrap multiselect enabled?