# Bootstrap multiselect dropdown not showing when using angular 2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using a [bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

It shows when I hardcode the options:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 form-group input-group btn-group" style="height:64px;">
        <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
            <select id="category-select" multiple class="form-control">
                <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
                <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
                <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
                <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
                <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
                <option value="onions">Onions</option>
            </select>
            <div class="form-control-icon" id="keywords-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But not when I use angular 2 syntax shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087823/3935156):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 form-group input-group btn-group" style="height:64px;">
        <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
            <select id="category-select" multiple class="form-control">
                <option *ngFor="#item of items">{{item}}</option>
            </select>
            <div class="form-control-icon" id="keywords-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It gets close...it has filled in the selects options:

[image]

It just won't display them. It won't even allow the mouse to right-click and inspect the multiselect. I have to right-click beside it then find it in the console elements. Which suggests maybe something to do with z-index, but kind of doubt that as I'm not sure why the z-index would be affected.

How do I get the dropdown to display when using angular 2 syntax instead of hardcoding the options? It worked for [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087823/3935156):

**EDIT: It actually never worked for that guy, checking the plunker he does not use the bootstrap multiselect plugin. I will leave the question here in case someone does get it working somehow.**

Answer (score 0):

You have the following attributes set on your select:

- disabled
- style="display:none"

Try removing them.