# How to convert this jQuery code to Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am following below jQuery example to convert it into Angular 2. Is there any way that How can i do it? Should i integrate jQuery in Angular 2 or any way in angular 2 to achieve this goal?

Example URL :

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/create-add-remove-select-lists-using-jquery/

Demo output :
 http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_create_add_remove_select_list.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Mark Rajcok's answer:

- [Angular2: how bind to select multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167463/angular2-how-bind-to-select-multiple/36089272#36089272)

You could implement this feature this way in the template:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>

    <select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple size="5" (change)="changeSelectFrom($event.target.options)">
      <option *ngFor="#elt of selectFromValues" [value]="elt.value">{{elt.name}}</option>
    </select>

    <a (click)="addElements()" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
    <a (click)="removeElements()" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>

    <select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple size="5" (change)="changeSelectTo($event.target.options)">
      <option *ngFor="#elt of selectToValues" [value]="elt.value">{{elt.name}}</option>
    </select>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

and in the component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('select-from') selectFromElRef;
  @ViewChild('select-to') selectToElRef;

  constructor() {
    this.selectFromValues = [
      { value: '1', name: 'Item 1' },
      { value: '2', name: 'Item 2' },
      { value: '3', name: 'Item 3' },
      { value: '4', name: 'Item 4' }
    ];

    this.selectToValues = [
      { value: '5', name: 'Item 5' },
      { value: '6', name: 'Item 6' },
      { value: '7', name: 'Item 7' }
    ];
  }

  getSelectedElements(options, values) {
    return Array.apply(null, options)
      .filter(option => option.selected)
      .map(option => {
        return values.find((elt) => elt.value === option.value);
      });
  }

  changeSelectFrom(options) {
    this.fromValues = this.getSelectedElements(options, this.selectFromValues);
  }

  changeSelectTo(options) {
    this.toValues = this.getSelectedElements(options, this.selectToValues);
  }

  addElements() {
    this.fromValues.forEach((elt) => {
      this.selectToValues.push(elt);
      let index = this.selectFromValues.findIndex((elt1) => elt1.value === elt.value);
      this.selectFromValues.splice(index, 1);
    });
  }

  removeElements() {
    this.toValues.forEach((elt) => {
      this.selectFromValues.push(elt);
      let index = this.selectToValues.findIndex((elt1) => elt1.value === elt.value);
      this.selectToValues.splice(index, 1);
    });
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/5SQVErbgDaTyvHnjw7Wh?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

A general rule of thumb: Do *not* mess around with the DOM when using Angular2, but *only* manipulate your data and let Ang2 do the rest using its data binding. This implies that I would never even consider using jQuery here.

The approach to take is:

- Add some data store to your component (or a service your component is using). This could be as simple as 2 arrays of the two lists.
- Modify your template so that the two form elements are constructed using the data store(s).
- When the user triggers an action using 1 of the 2 buttons, change the data store accordingly.
- That’s it. Ang2 will do all the work for you.