# Is it possible to bind a multiple select to an array in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have a multiple select and I need to somehow bind what the user selects but I'm having trouble doing so. I tried setting the ngModel to an array of strings that I was hoping would serve as the values that the user selected, but no luck.

Is this supported in Angular 2? If not, is there a workaround? I've tried a few different things but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167463/angular2-how-bind-to-select-multiple?rq=1

Comment: Made a plunker for you. https://plnkr.co/edit/E9FvEZKajbTN2WzE0trG?p=preview