# How to get value of multiple select option in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have added a multiple select using this plunker http://jsfiddle.net/ishanbakshi/fyhsz9ra/ .and it's working succesfully but now i want to get the value of multiple select in ng-model(angularjs).nad i have tried like this.but failed.

Code:

```
  <select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px" name="cities" ng-init="get_city_by_search()" ng-model="submitAdsFormData.cities[$index]">
      <option value="{{x.id}}" ng-repeat ="x in searchResult">{{x.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

So, can anyone help me to get this.Thanks in advance.and also any help will be appreciated.

Comment: may be this will solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167463/angular2-how-bind-to-select-multiple

Comment: @UsamaAzam the link you provided is about Angular (2+). The OP is asking a question about AngularJS (1.x)

Comment: @lealceldeiro so have you got my question?

Comment: Yes, @dev_02, but I need to see an example of what you're doing exactly in order to help you better. So far, I can see that you are using `$index` outside the `ng-repeat`. I also saw the jsfiddle you provided but there is no AngularJS code there. Can you make a jsfiddle with your actual code.