# Select value from multiselect dropdown in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, multi-select, adminlte

I have used adminlte multiselect dropdown, but I can't get the exact value from the selected option.

I have used below code:

```
<select class="form-control selectMultipleCompany multipleCompany" formControlName="multipleCompany" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select a Company" style="width: 100%;">
    <option *ngFor="let company of Companies" [value]="company.CpmCode">
    {{company.CpmName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

when I get selected value so it will get like this

> [{ "0" : "15" } ,{ "1" : "20"}]

but I want comma separated value like `15,20`

i used bellow code :

```
$(".multipleCompany").val();
```

Comment: your select is missing a two way data binding for the value [()] and you dont need to use jquery since you are using angularJs

Comment: so how i get, you have any answer or idea? @SérgioS.Filho

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167463/angular2-how-bind-to-select-multiple