# Display dropdown box with checkbox

Tags: php

```
 <select name="city[]" id="CitySD" class="select required" multiple> 
  <option value=""><?php echo $this->Lang["SEL_COUNTRY"]; ?></option>
  <?php
  foreach ($this->all_city_list as $c)
  {
        ?> 
        <option <?php
        if (isset($this->userPost['city']))
        {
              if ($c->city_id == $this->userPost['city'])
              {
                    ?> selected <?php
                    }
              }
              ?> title="<?php echo $c->city_name; ?>"value="<?php echo $c->city_id; ?>">
                    <?php echo $c->city_name; ?>
        </option>
  <?php } ?> 
 </select>
```

Above is my city drop down field in registration page,if user select country means then only the city filed gets active and its display city based on user selection country.
I want to display cities in the city drop down with individual checkbox option for all cities and select all option check box,the user can click select all means it will select all cities and deselect means it will deselect all cities and user can also select random cities.
please anyone can help me!

Comment: why not multi select for cities

Comment: Its for one E-commerce project...the user can select multiple cities and filter the products based on selected cities

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion

Comment: how i fix select all option checkbox for above u suggested