# How to add Check box to JQuery Select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I am using jquery select2 plugin for multiple select. Here I want to add a checkbox for each select option.

The dropdown option should be selected based on the checkbox checked/unchecked attr.

**HTML:**

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="e1" style="width:300px">
    <option value="AL" selected> Alabama</option>
    <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
    <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
    <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#e1").select2();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/3149/)**

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option. this should give you the first steps to implement your issue

Comment: I need this with Select2.js plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jEADR/3155/)**

You could toggle class instead of using `checkbox`, check the example below.

**HTML :**

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="e1" style="width:300px">
    <option value="AL" selected> Alabama</option>
    <option value="Am" selected>Amalapuram</option>
    <option value="An" selected>Anakapalli</option>
    <option value="Ak" selected>Akkayapalem</option>
    <option value="WY" selected>Wyoming</option>
</select>

<button type='button' id='submit'>Submit</button>
```

**JS :**

```
$("#e1").select2();

$('body').on('click','.select2-search-choice', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('selected')
})

$('body').on('click','#submit', function(){
  $('#s2id_e1 .select2-search-choice.selected').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
  })
})
```

**CSS :**

```
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-choice.selected{
    background-color: #286090;
    border-color: #204d74;
    color: #FFF;
    background-image : none;
}
```

Hope this helps.