# option tag inside the checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying multi-select inside checkbox in angular 4 but it not coming to the checkbox in front of name please help me, anyone

this is my HTML

```
<select class="form-control" name="assigned_teams" id="assigned_teams" [(ngModel)]="advisorData.assigned_teams" multiple-size="5" multiple>
                            <option [ngValue]="aTeam" *ngFor="let aTeam of assignTeams"><input type="checkbox">{{aTeam.name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
```

Comment: do you want a multiple dropdown or checkbox ?

Comment: I want both checkbox and drop down

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understand you correctly, but you need to set the `value` property of the input with aTeam.name...

Comment: name coming correctly. but before i want to checkbox

Comment: can you please post an example what you exactly want to reach?

Comment: I want exactly like this <select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="assigned_teams" multiple="" multiple-size="5" name="assigned_teams" ng-reflect-name="assigned_teams">
        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}--><option ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" value="0: Object"><input type="checkbox"/>Team 5
        </option>


<option ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" value="1: Object"><input type="checkbox"/>Team A
        </option><option ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]" value="2: Object"><input type="checkbox"/>Team 6</option></select>

Comment: So, you want to have checkboxes inside your dropdown, is that correct?
Then please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option