# angular2 multi select checkbox

Tags: html, angular2-directives

Hi I am new to angular2 and type script. I am trying to develop multiselect dropdown in angularjs2. I have my plain html as below. I refered [How to use Checkbox inside Select Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option) from stackoverflow.

```
   <div class="selectBox" (click)="showCheckboxes()">
                            </div>

                            <div id="checkboxes" [style.display]="expanded ? 'block' : 'none'">
                                <label for="one">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox
                                </label>
                                <label for="two">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox
                                </label>
                                <label for="three">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox
                                </label>
                            </div>
```

in component i have

```
 showCheckboxes() {
     expanded =expanded;
    }
```

also i declared expanded = false; in component. 
function showCheckboxes is written in js. I am trying to write same thing in type script. Can someone help me to make it work on angular2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're aware of Angular basics such as components.

So the method in your component should look like:

```
expanded = false;
showCheckboxes() {
  expanded = !expanded;
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<div class="selectBox" (click)="showCheckboxes()">
   ....
</div>

<div id="checkboxes" [style.display]="expanded ? 'block' : 'none'">
   ....
</div>
```

Or you can even remove method and move code to HTML:

```
<div class="selectBox" (click)="expanded=!expanded;">
```

And in your component you will left only:

```
expanded = false;
```

Comment: Thanks. i am aware of basics.  I started getting error near   expanded = !expanded; cannot find name expanded did you mean instance member this.expanded?

Comment: You need to declare it in component: expanded = false;

Comment: I've added explanation to my answer. You will move code of function showCheckbox to HTML but the variable expanded you need to declare anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my code above same as i have in my pages. I am not getting anything in my page.

Comment: Could you please insert Angular component code to your question? Also I've mentioned that your HTML is not the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option

Comment: Issue with cache. I fixed it. Thanks. If i want to bind values to checkboxes from api then i should write my code in showCheckboxes function right?

Comment: If you mean you want to display content from api to id="checkboxes" then you need to use *ngFor and an array.  showChexboxes() should have logic only for showing/hiding checkboxes and nothing more. If you want to add an extra logic when to show or hide them then yes you can write it back to your component.

Comment: You're welcome. I would suggest to read this article about using http, maybe it will help you: https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/04/02/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-6-consuming-real-data-with-http/