# how to implement multi checkbox dropdown without any third party libraries

Tags: drop-down-menu, dropdown, checkboxlist

How to implement multi checkbox drop down without any third party libraries.

We want a dropdown having checkboxes not in jquery and javascript. we want pure server side control
.

Comment: Unless you provide what you tried so far and are stuck with a specific problem, the site is not designed to code for you. In this case, you should look for online courses, tutorials or hire professional coding services. See also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Pure server side control means you will only rely on the HTML standards.
The HTML *Select* element has a [*multiple*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple) attribute which lets the user choose multiple values.
[The HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-select-element) doesn't require a specific rendering layout which lets the browser free from any constraints. Most of the time, selected options are simply hightlighted, plus the *multiple* attribute makes the select element to loose its dropdown looking style (you can reduce its height using the [*size*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-size) attribute).

```html
<!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
<p>Maintain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key down to select multiple elements</p>
<select name="multi" multiple size="2">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
  <option value="value4">Value 4</option>
  <option value="value5">Value 5</option>
  <option value="value6">Value 6</option>
  <option value="value7">Value 7</option>
  <option value="value8">Value 8</option>
  <option value="value9">Value 9</option>
  <option value="value10">Value 10</option>
</select>
```

If you change your mind about using Javascript, you could implement what [this well detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option#answer-27547021) suggests as it requires just very few additional Javascript and css and but no library.