# Not able to display checkbox in multiple select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-select

I have a select dropdown with multiselect checkbox option

Initial View

[image]

After selecting value

[image]

Selection of value is working fine, but in the first image the checkbox are not visible

I have used [bootstrap select multiple select box](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#multiple-select-boxes)  functionality.

code:

```
<select class="form-control fruits selectpicker" multiple  id="fruits" name="fruits" title="fruits">
    <option value="">apple </option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    <option value="grapes">grapes</option>
  </select>
```

I want that in the first image the checkbox should be visible, can anyone tell me how to display it

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly do you want? Also can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: @ Smit Raval i want a check box inside the dropdown on click of that checkbox it should get selected.

Comment: @lakshmipriya   so you mean to say checboxes are coming, just not visible initially. When you click on it, it checked and start showing?

Comment: Perhaps you can find your solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with selectpicker.

Here is a solution:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/yourcode.js"></script>

....
.dropdown-item:not(.selected) span.check-mark::before {
    content: "\f0c8" !important;
    border:0;
    transform: rotate(0);
}
.bootstrap-select.show-tick .dropdown-item:not(.selected) span.check-mark {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 15px;
    top: 5px;
}



....
$('#selector').selectpicker({iconBase: 'fontawesome',tickIcon: 'far fa-check-square'});
```