# Using list as select inside form

Tags: php, html, css

I was wondering if there is any whay to **use styled list as select box** for form input. Or if there is any similar solution where you can style select box with icons and more. Because my PHP validation fails.

**PHP**

```
 // Validate prioriteta
    if(empty(trim($_POST["prioriteta"]))){
        $prioriteta_err = "Prosim izberite prioriteto.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM tasks WHERE prioriteta = ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_prioriteta);

        // Set parameters
        $param_prioriteta = trim($_POST["prioriteta"]);

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            /* store result */
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $prioriteta = trim($_POST["prioriteta"]);
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" list="seznam" name="prioriteta" value="<?php echo $prioriteta; ?>">
<small class="text-muted control "><?php echo $prioriteta_err; ?></small>
<ul id="seznam" class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><i class="far fa-circle red pr-2" value="ZP"></i>Very High</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-circle purple pr-2" value="PO"></i>High</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-circle aquamarine pr-2" value="SR"></i>Mid</li>
  <li><i class="far fa-circle med-gray pr-2" value="NI"></i>Low</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, there is. Where did you get stuck? What went wrong? Where's your code?

Comment: May be easier to add style to a select box, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option

Comment: @DavidThomas This code can't pass php validation. I was wondering if this is wrong usage of list item.

Comment: In order to submit the values to the server you would need to use a hidden `<select>` element to 'carry' the name=value pairs (assuming the validation errors happen when the form is submitted. Use the list as a styled select, when selecting values in the list trigger selection of the relevant options within the select. (Comment edited, I misunderstood the meaning of 'validation' for a moment.)

Comment: @DavidThomas With checking if variable is empty. I added PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use invisible input field and then on list item click get values and insert them into input field.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="prioriteta" value="<?php echo $prioriteta; ?>"
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).val();
});

});
```