# Programmatically put labels in div or label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to set the value of my label (or div) as an element and not text.

Example, this code creates a list of checkboxes as followed in this post [How to use Checkbox inside Select Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option) :

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="checkboxesList">
  <label for="one">
     <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
  <label for="two">
    <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox</label>
  <label for="three">
    <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
</asp:Label>
```

I need to create my List in CodeBehind and not directly in ASPX I tried :

```
checkboxesList.Text = "<label for=\"one\"> < input type = \"checkbox\" id = \"one\" /> First checkbox </ label > <label for= \"two\" > < input type = \"checkbox\" id = \"two\" /> Second checkbox </ label >";
```

Doing so it only prints as a string and do not create the differents labels.
How to implement it from the code behind having just :

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="checkboxesList">
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: so did u face any error or exception?

Comment: @ershoaib No, the way I am doing it only prints the full string

Comment: try to use `asp:Literal` instead of `asp:Label`

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use server-side controls to generate all HTML elements. It is possible to use HTML directly for container elements. Use server-side controls only for elements that should be accessible from server code.

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    <label>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="one" runat="server" Text="First checkbox" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="two" runat="server" Text="Second checkbox" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="three" runat="server" Text="Third checkbox" />
    </label>
</div>
```

The snippet allows you to get/set values and text of checkboxes on server-side. Also you will be able to add server-side click event handler for each of the checkbox.

Note, the [`for`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_for.asp) attribute is used to bound the `<label>` with `<input>` that is not placed inside the `<label>`. Moreover the attribute is not supported by IE. So, in your case it is possible to place checkboxes into labels instead of using of `for` attribute.

Also you need to know the HTML `id` attribute in general case is not equal to ASP `ID` value. Therefore, if you want to link controls using `for` attribute, then set `id` attribute value through [`ClientID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientid) property.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for the answers.

I've finally decided to use a CheckBoxList :

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="LabelList">
    <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ClientIDMode="Predictable" DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Name" ID="specificInfoListControl" Width="150">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</asp:Label>
```

And I retrieve the values with :

```
foreach (ListItem item in specificInfoListControl.Items)
{
  if (item.Selected)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: The markup that is generated by the snippet is not [valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html#validation_basics). The [`<label>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) tag defines a label for **an** `<input>` element. Your markup will contain multiple inputs in one label.