# Checkboxes for SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**.Net Core 2.1**

I have a working multi select drop-down list implemented using:

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="SelectedItems" asp-items="Model.ItemDropdownOptions" multiple size="20"></select>
```

The page received the following populated view model:

```
public class AllocateDocumentViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Document Id")]
    public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Document Name")]
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Document Description")]
    public string DocumentDescription { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Items")]
    public List<SelectListItem> ItemDropdownOptions { get; set; }

    public Guid[] SelectedItems { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller receives this model:

```
public class AllocateDocumentsPostModel
{
    public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }
    public Guid[] SelectedItems { get; set; }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> AllocateDocument(AllocateDocumentsPostModel model)
{
 ......
}
```

This is all working just fine. It allows users to hold the  key down and multi select items. It also correctly populates the form with the currently selected items.

But, user feedback is that they want a checkbox next to each item in the list.

I have found a few examples of how to do this with unordered lists but is there a way to somehow do this with the existing select?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pure css to implement that :

CSS:

```
<style>
    .select-checkbox option::before {
        content: "\2610";
        width: 1.3em;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .select-checkbox option:checked::before {
        content: "\2611";
    }
</style>
```

Add `select-checkbox` class name to select in view :

```
<select class="form-control select-checkbox" asp-for="SelectedItems" asp-items="Model.ItemDropdownOptions" multiple size="20"></select>
```

But that checkbox is a "fake" checkbox otherwise you add real checkbox controls like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547021/5751404) or you can use  some plugins like [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/) .