# HTML form with checkbox for multiple value

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a Checkbox field in html input form. In this the value are fetched from another table.I want to select the multiple user with the help of this check box.What is wrong with my code

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label> Supervised BY( At IUAC)<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="user" > <br>
   <checkbox value=""> </checkbox>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * from  tblstaff ";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{               ?>  
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->name);?></option>
 <?php }} ?>
```

I tried this code bu it is not showing the check box

Comment: `<option>` tag is for the `<select>` statement, quite different from a checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

Use input type `Checkbox` field Like this

```
<?php 

foreach($results as $result)
{               ?>  

<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $result->name; ?>" value="<?php echo $result->name; ?>"> <?php echo $result->name; ?> </br>

 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`<input type="checkbox">`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp)

Correct code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label> Supervised BY( At IUAC)<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>

<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * from  tblstaff ";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{
?>  
<input type="checkbox" name="user" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->name);?><br>
<?php
}}
  ?>
```

**Edit**:
Try with `multiple` attribute of `<select>`

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * from  tblstaff ";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
echo "<select name='user' multiple>";
foreach($results as $result)
{
?>  
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->name);?></option>
<?php
}
echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

Comment: it is working fine but it display the complete list. i want it should come in dropdown  with check box.I tried with selectt option but no joy

Comment: any one having  any idea plz

Comment: any more suggestion plz

Comment: I think you are telling about `multiple` attribute of `<select>` tag

Comment: but it will not show the check box.It requires the Ctrl key to select multiple

Comment: Ok this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/25414909/10273906 see demo also

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bootstrap-multiselect` Like This

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Dropdown Multi Select</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.12/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<form id="formone">

<div style="padding:20px">

<select id="chkone" multiple="multiple">

<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * from  tblstaff ";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{               ?>  
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->name);?></option>
 <?php }} ?>

</select>

</div>

</form>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $('#chkone').multiselect({

        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });

});

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label> Supervised BY( At IUAC)<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>

<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * from  tblstaff ";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{               ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="user[]" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>" ><?php echo htmlentities($result->name);?>   
 <?php }} ?>
```

when you will submit the form, you will get $_POST['user'] as an array of user ids's that are checked.