# Is there a way to put checkboxes inside a Select with antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm looking for a way to put checkboxes in an **antd** Select, instead of the icon displayed when an item is selected.

[image]

I have tried to use the **menuItemSelectedIcon** prop, but it only displays the Checkbox when the item is selected, which is not what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to display a checkbox that is checked when the item is selected, and isn't when the item isn't.

I'm kind of looking for an equivalent of the "treeCheckable" prop available for the TreeSelect.

Is there a way to put checkboxes inside a (simple) Select ?

Comment: sosmething like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution that uses antd features, but thank your for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

use `menuItemSelectedIcon` this prop... u can read abut it in Api section of Select component. Then, do same style in options focus, active & select selector. style should be such as the icon that you will use became different color when it is focused, active or select. you can change options global classname when it will be selected. By doing this, it will look like the checkbox is working but behind the scene it's just a icon of checkbox which will change style .