# How to push data to 2d array with predefined result

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have several inputs, let's say here are two inputs like the following:

```
const first = 50;
const second = [[14, 16], [28, 30]];
```

How can i get the following result:

`expected result = [[0, 13], [14, 16], [17, 27], [28, 30], [31, 50]];`

Now my code is like this and still confused to arrange the correct logic, thank you

```
const first = 50;
const second = [[14, 16], [28, 30]].flat(1);

let result = [];
for(let i = 0; i < second.length; i++) {
   let temp = second[i];
   if (i === 0) {
     result.push([i, temp - 1]);
   }
   result.push([i+temp, temp+2]);
}

console.log(result); // output [[0, 13], [14, 16], [17, 18], [30, 30], [33, 32]]
```

[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/lukabobiwi/edit?js,console)

Comment: What if `first` is greater than the smallest value in `second`, or smaller than the largest value in `second`?

Comment: variable "first" always greater than "second"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating over the array of arrays. push *the array being iterated over itself* to the result. Examine its second value to determine where the next iteration should start at.

```js
const first = 50;
const second = [[14, 16], [28, 30]];

const result = [];
let start = 0;
while (second.length) {
  const secondItem = second.shift();
  result.push([start, secondItem[0] - 1]);
  result.push(secondItem);
  start = secondItem[1] + 1;
}
if (start < first) {
  result.push([start, first]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi could you help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74015538/15916627