# Change a <select> in react to multiselect

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, express, multi-select

I need that when selecting the option Consultations, the selection of procedures is unique, and when selecting the option laboratory tests, the selection of procedures is multiple.

[image]

```
                {/* Seção 3 */}
                <div className="formulario-section2">
                    <div className="formulario-campos-tip-pro">
                        <div className="formulario-campo2">
                            <label htmlFor="tipoSolicitacao">Tipo de Solicitação*</label>
                            <select
                                className="campos"
                                id="tipoSolicitacao"
                                value={tipoSolicitacao}
                                onChange={(e) => setTipoSolicitacao(e.target.value)}
                            >
                                <option value="">Selecione um tipo de solicitação</option>
                                {tipoSolicitacaoOptions.map((option) => (
                                    <option key={option.id} value={option.descricao}>
                                        {option.descricao}
                                    </option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div className="formulario-campo2">
                            <label htmlFor="procedimentos">Procedimentos*</label>
                            <select
                                className="campos"
                                id="procedimentos"
                                value={procedimentos}
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                    // Se a opção "Tipo de Solicitação" for "Exames Laboratoriais", atualize o estado com as opções selecionadas em um array
                                    if (tipoSolicitacao === "Exames Laboratoriais") {
                                        const selectedOptions = Array.from(
                                            e.target.selectedOptions,
                                            (option) => option.value
                                        );
                                        setProcedimentos(selectedOptions);
                                    } else {
                                        // Caso contrário, trate como seleção única como antes.
                                        setProcedimentos([e.target.value]);
                                    }
                                }}
                                // Adicione o atributo `multiple` quando o "Tipo de Solicitação" for "Exames Laboratoriais"
                                multiple={tipoSolicitacao === "Exames Laboratoriais"}
                                style={selectStyle} // Adicione o estilo ao campo de seleção
                            >
                                <option value="">Selecione um procedimento</option>
                                {procedimentosFiltrados.map((procedimento) => (
                                    <option key={procedimento.id} value={procedimento.descricao}>
                                        {procedimento.descricao}
                                    </option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I am not able to put a checkbox inside the select

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSU7F.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot place checkbox inside select element but you can get the same functionality by using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

[How to use Checkbox inside Select Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option)

Comment: or you can also use `react-select`.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-dijkstra-n6k89f?file=/src/App.js
Please check this, as it might help