# Multi select dropdown with checkboxes using Angular (no bootstap or angularJs modules)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have a website without using twitter bootstap or madterial design.

Can changing a dropdown to be one with multi checkbox selection be easy as adding
an `input` inside the `select` element? Why isn't this enough?

```
            <select ...  id="gadsCustomerId">
                <option *ngFor="let cust_list of customer_list" [value]=cust_list.id>{{ cust_list.account_name }} [{{ cust_list.id }}]</option>
            </select>`
```

to:

```
  <select ...  id="gadsCustomerId">
    <option *ngFor="let cust_list of customer_list" [value]="cust_list.id">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cust_list.isSelected"> {{ cust_list.account_name }} [{{ cust_list.id }}] </option>  
</select>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547021/17038313