# Font Awesome & Unicode

Tags: html, css, unicode, font-awesome

I'm using (the excellent) Font-Awesome in my site, and it's working fine, if I use it this way:

```
<i class="icon-home"></i>
```

But (for some reasons) I want to use it in the Unicode way, like:

```
<i>&#xf015;</i>
```

([Font Awesome's cheatsheet](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/))

But it doesn't work - the browser shows a square instead.

How do I solve this? 
The CSS path is correct (as the first way of using Font Awesome works).

Edit: I do have the FontAwesome.otf installed.

Comment: please post a jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net

Comment: I don't have access to all the files now, I just want to know how to use web font with unicode.

Comment: try setting this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` on your page.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It does not work, because `<i>&#xf015;</i>` simply asks the browser to display the Private Use code point U+F015 using an italic typeface. The Font Awesome CSS code has nothing that would affect this. If you add `class=icon-home` to the tag, you will get the glyph assigned to U+F015 in the FontAwesome font, but you will get it twice, due to the way the Font Awesome trickery works.

To get the glyph just once, you need to use CSS that asks for the use of the FontAwesome font without triggering the rules that add a glyph via generated content. A simple trick is to use a class name that starts with `icon-` but does not match any of the predefined names in Font Awesome or any name otherwise used in your CSS or JavaScript code. E.g.,

```
<i class=icon-foo>&#xf015;</i>
```

Alternatively, use CSS code that sets `font-family: FontAwesome` and `font-style: normal` on the `i` element.

PS. Note that Private Use code points such as U+F015 have, by definition, no interoperable meaning. Consequently, when style sheets are disabled, `&#xf015;` will not be displayed as any character; the browser will use its way of communicating the presence of undefined data, such as a small box, possibly containing the code point number.

Comment: +1 for the PS. The whole idea of symbol fonts like FontAwesome is, in my opinion, alien to the intended design of Unicode and the Web, and generally harmful.

Comment: +1. Does the use of unicode impact performances ? I feel like it could since it wouldn't need to use the pseudo element :before and define the content.

Comment: With FontAwesome 5, I found that `font-family: FontAwesome;` no longer works. I had to use `font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;` instead.

Comment: @TomWarner's comment is super helpful. that's the correct way of setting the `font-family`. note - it may also be necessary to set the `font-weight` to something other than normal. in my case I needed to set it to bold for the icon to appear.

Comment: @aberkow Thank you for the font-weight tip. I can confirm that it works now.

Answer (score 94):

I got a similar problem using unicode and fontawesome.
When I wrote:

```
font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
content: "\f061"; /* FontAwesome Unicode */
```

On Google Chrome, a square appears instead of the icon.
The new version of Font Awesome also requires

```
font-weight: 900;
```

That works for me.

From: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/11946

Comment: Yep, font-weight is required now. Thanks.

Comment: This saved me. I was missing the font-weight. Thanks Basile!

Comment: Font Awesome 5 Now requires font-weight:900 for solid

Comment: That did the trick! thanks a lot! Really bizarre that some work without and some require the weight....

Answer (score 43):

You must use the `fa` class:

```
<i class="fa">
   &#xf000;
</i>

<i class="fa fa-2x">
   &#xf000;
</i>
```

Answer (score 27):

For those who may stumble across this post, you need to set

```
font-family: FontAwesome;
```

as a property in your CSS selector and then unicode will work fine in CSS

Comment: In my case, I had to change this to `font-family: Font Awesome 5 Pro; `

Comment: Yes, this is for 4.7 version.

Comment: this is what we all should do ;) thanks !

Answer (score 8):

I have found that in Font-Awesome version 5 (free), you have you add: 
"**font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;**" only then it seems to be working properly.

This has worked for me :)

I hope some finds this helpful

Comment: Thank you! I checked the Font Awesome CSS and this seemed to be the answer, but there's multiple variants (depending on if a pro license has been bought). This solved the mystery for me.

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to load the FontAwesome style before yours.

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
font-weight: 400;
content: "\f007";
```

You can find FontAwesome's explainations here:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 5):

There are three different font families that I know of that you can choose from and each has its own weight element that needs to be applied:

First

`font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
content: "\f373";`

Second

`font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
content: "\f061";
font-weight: 900;`

Third

`font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';`

Reference here - https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I found that this worked

```
content: "\f2d7" !important;
font-family: FontAwesome !important;
```

It didn't seem to work without the !important for me.

Here's a tutorial on how to change social icons with Unicodes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jgDs2agkE0&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that you may need to include a version number too as you could be using either:

```
font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
```

or

```
font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
```

Answer (score 2):

In latest 5.13 there's a difference.
You do like always...

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
content: "\f107";
```

But there's a difference now... Instead of use font-weight: 500; You are following this:

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
font-weight: 900;
content: "\f107";
```

Why is that? I figure out by finding in in .fas class, so you can figure out an updated way by looking into .fas class so you're doing the same as it has to be. Figure out if there's a font-weight and font-family. Here you go guys. That's an update answer for 5.13.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using Font Awesome version 4.7,

```
css_selector::before{
content:"\f006";
font-family:"fontawesome";
font-weight:900;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add font weight 900..its working for me

```
font-weight: 900;
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the answer of *davidhund* on [this page](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/180) I came up with a solution that your web font isn't loaded correctly that me be a issue of wrong paths.

**Here is what he said:**

> My first guess is that you include the FontAwesome webfont from a
>   different (sub-)domain. So make sure you set the correct headers on
>   those webfont-files: "you'll need to add the
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, whitelisting the domain you're
>   pulling the asset from."
>   https://github.com/h5bp/html5boilerplate.com/blob/master/src/.htaccess#L78-86

And also look at the [font-gotchas](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/font-face-gotchas/) :)

Hope I am clear and helped you :)

On the same page, *f135ta* said:

> ...I fixed the issue by uploading the file "fontawesome-webfont.ttf"
>   to my webserver and installing it like a regular font.. I dont know if
>   its part of the pre-req's for using it anyway, but it works for me ;-

Comment: can't be, because my site is still local, just some html. I don't even need to use WAMP/XAMPP in order to check it. And the font IS installed locally

Comment: then what about the paths? are they correct? **double-check** them!

Comment: They must be correct, because when I use the font with this way
'<i class="icon-home"></i>' 
it works

Comment: what about you .htaccess? you can put it on your local directories aswell but you need to use a local server like WAMP or XAMPP

Comment: I'll check it, it may take some time. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the FontAwesome icon with the CSS3 pseudo selector as shown below.
[image]

Ensure to set the font-family to FontAwesome as shown below:

```
table.dataTable thead th.sorting:after {font-family: FontAwesome;}
```

To get the above working, you must do the following:

1. Download the FontAwesome css library here [FontAwesome v4.7.0](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/)
2. Extract from the zip file and include into your app root folder, the two folders as shown below:
   [image]
3. Reference only the css folder in the `<head></head>` section of your app as shown below:
   [image]

Comment: Pictures of code are not helpful. They can't be copy/pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on Jukka K. Korpela answer above, font awesome already defined a css selector "fa". You can simply do `<i class="fa">&#xf015;</i>` . The catch here is, fa defines the font-style:normal, if you need italic, you can override like `<i class="fa" style="font-style:italic">&#xf015;</i>`

Answer (score 0):

By using css you can add your icon via Unicode

```
content: '\f144';
font-family: FontAwesome;
```

This will work