# Why aren't these icons rendering using v-html directive in a select menu?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, font-awesome

I am trying to use unicode Font Awesome 5 icons to render in a select menu's **options** tag specifically.

The option elements have the v-html directive on them:

```
<option
  v-html="item.display_value"
  v-for="(item, i) in fieldData.values" :key="i"
  :value="item.internal_value">
</option>
```

If `display_value` is equal to `'&#xf1b9; Car'` it will not render the icon.
If `display_value` is equal to `'&#9824; Car'` it will render a spade.

So it seems like there is an issue of font awesome unicode being recognized on that element (yes I also tried setting the font-family on that element to the font awesome family).

Also tried using  tags and that doesn't work.

Expected output should be select dropdown with various Font Awesome 5 icons along with text as options in the menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Awesome & Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254339/font-awesome-unicode)

Comment: That didn't fix it. This is a different obstacle given that it sits within <option> tags, I think

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743041/font-awesome-icon-in-select-option