# How to use fontawesome-icon component in bootstrap-select component in vue app?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, bootstrap-vue

I would like to use the font-awesome-icon component in a b-form-select-option component in my vue app.

```
  <b-form-select id="icon-select" v-model="selected">
    <b-form-select-option :value="coffee"><font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'coffee']" /></b-form-select-option>
    <b-form-select-option :value="user-secret"><font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'user-secret']" /></b-form-select-option>
  </b-form-select>

<script>
    import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
    import { faUserSecret, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
    library.add(faUserSecret, faCoffee);
    
      export default  {
        name: 'rooms-vue',
    
        props: [],
        data () {
          return {
            selected: null,
        }
      }
</script>
```

The code looks (condensed) as above. The icons are not being display. What am I missing out?

Until now, I have found e.g. this thread:
[Font Awesome Icons not loading as expected in Option List (But are when selected)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63144268/font-awesome-icons-not-loading-as-expected-in-option-list-but-are-when-selected)

But as far as I understand, this is not the suggested way in the fortawesome specs.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I don't think what you want to do is actually possible. Looking at the documentation, there is a possibility to use `html` to display html in the select tag when using `options` array, but it also says `Only basic/native HTML is supported in the html field. Note that not all browsers will render inline html (i.e. <i>, <strong>, etc.) inside <option> elements of a <select>.` https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#options-property

Comment: Is this the code that you have? Are you using `Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)` in your `main.js`?

Comment: @ImanShafiei: yes, i have the Vue component registered in my main:Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);

Comment: Could you please share the complete code that you have in your `main.js`? And please make sure that you are doing the same thing from the documentation: https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome

Comment: @ImanShafiei - thanks for your aid  - please find below my condensed main.js:


`import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './router'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app'); `

Comment: I think you should import the icon that you want to use like: `import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'` and use it in your `app.vue` : `<font-awesome-icon icon="user-secret" />`

Comment: Thanks iman, I have it imported in my component. Tbh, I am afraif @AJT82 is right. The docs say:
"Only basic/native HTML is supported in the html field (components will not work). " This is pretty much disappointing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your welcome, I was thinking, and maybe If this is just for some of your options, you can use the `svg` or use `Unicode`. Look at this post that gives you more ideas.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254339/font-awesome-unicode