# Why doesn't a free fontawesome icon show up when using CodePen?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, codepen

The CodePen is https://codepen.io/ericg_off/pen/wvORewY

The CSS is:

```
.fa-test {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="fa-test">
  &#xf007
</div>

<div class="fa-test">
  &#xf3c5
</div>
```

The CodePen result looks like:

[image: codepen result]

FontAwesome does show f3c5 (location-dot) as a free icon...

[image: FontAwesome]

[image: location-dot]

The other free icon I am using, f007 (user), does work.

Where it gets a bit stranger is that if I use this same code with a Stack Overflow snippet, the location-dot icon will show up.

```css
.fa-test {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="fa-test">
  &#xf007
</div>

<div class="fa-test">
  &#xf3c5
</div>
```

What needs to change about how I am using CodePen so the free location-dot icon will show up when using FontAwesome 6.5.1?

Comment: It doesn't show up in SO snippet for me.

Comment: Location dot doesn't show up on the SO snippet for me. But why ? Why don't you use the classic way of using these icons ?

Comment: Me either, it shows up . The font doesn't have the character. Go SVG: https://codepen.io/jaycrav3ns/pen/poYLOxE

Comment: you have to use  `font-weight: 900;` .. look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254339/font-awesome-unicode). The answers and comments have some noise.. I checked myself, `font-weight` is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set font-weight to 900 in your css class.

Comment: Some explanation of why this works, how it was discovered, etc. would be good...