# CSS class with images show as 'content', how?

Tags: css

i'm with some doubts here, i've trying to find a tutorial or example on 'how to' but i can't find any.

I have a good knowledge in css (not professional, but i understand) and when working with some templates or tutorials i've seen some flat icons on the website, when i go to the css class, what i found is something like these: "example:before { content: "\e00a"; }"

I'd like to know how is it done? How can i change it to another icon? Or even, how can i create another 'flat icon' based on the same process?

If anyone can help me, please.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971474/cannot-view-the-source-image-file-on-a-website

Answer (score 1):

You can use the content property for icons for example. `\e00a` for example refers to this character: 

It can be used as the bullet point for list items:

```
li:before {
    content:'\e00a'
    padding-right:12px;
}
```

Some fonts come with characters like the ones [found here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/). You can use those characters like `\f042` for example to display the screen contrast symbol. however you will need to download the font first to make use of it. Read more about [@font-face here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Predefined CSS files like "[fontawsome](http://fontawesome.io)" or "[glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/)" (Google It). And then use their css class like `<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>` this will show facebook icon.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `font icons`. This gives you scalable vector icons that can be customized with CSS on size, color, drop-shadow, etc. -- Font Awesome

Here is a great example.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/