# Image generated from CSS content code

Tags: html, css

On a website I saw some interesting elements and inspected them. This is how the element looked like:
[image]

The CSS definition:

```
.entry-meta .date a:before {
    content: "\f303";
}
```

I know images can be embedded using the `url` property of `content` but in this case, there is no URL. What is this evil magic?

Comment: It's a reference to a Unicode character. It's not an image.

Comment: ... and there's likely an `@font-face` declaration with icons

Comment: @Xander Can you give me a link where I can read more about such declarations with '@' please? I don't even know what term to google for.

Comment: google "css `@font-face`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the icon that is **not** an image but a unicode character.

[Font-Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) uses this also.

See [this file](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/5a7e14b7cf5252702c4cf5da043cd73852e6f17a/css/font-awesome.css#L190-L1338):

```
/* Font Awesome uses the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA) to ensure screen
readers do not read off random characters that represent icons */
.fa-glass:before {
  content: "\f000";
}
.fa-music:before {
  content: "\f001";
}
.fa-search:before {
  content: "\f002";
}
...
```

Comment: was wondering that myself. (+1 was mine). Your answer is correct. However, the LESS *does* tend to obfuscate the answer. That's some weird looking code to someone who only knows css.

Comment: @ZachL That's a good point. I updated the answer with real CSS code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That `\f303` is a unicode symbol (just a *normal* text character). They are likely using a special font like Font-Awesome where all letters/numbers/etc.. are replaced with vector images.

[Here's an example using the Font-Awesome library](http://jsfiddle.net/c729N/1/)

```
p:before {
    content: "\f143";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10393517/363701) for more info on using Unicode values in your css.