# linking image with content on hover

Tags: css, hover

I hope you can help me. I was trying to hover an image with "add to cart" like here: https://spacewallet.de/shop
I dont know, what I am doing wrong here, can you help?

```css
.hunderter {
    background: url(http://neuronade.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/Shop-Produktbild_Bundle_englisch-min-mhvx28jvtfhpc0dhkugvgrvgvg1h17l9ze3zkr118a.jpg);
    display: block;
    background-size: 100%;
    border: transparent !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

a.hunderter:hover {
    background-color: rgba(100,230,230,0.5);
    background-position: 0 0;
    content:"&#9205; &#10145;Zum Warenkorb hinzufügen";
}
```

```html
<a href="/?preview_id=4212&preview_nonce=a62d30b2b8&preview=true&add-to-cart=5767" class="hunderter"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a few notes:

**1)** Your image should probably be part of the HTML. It will be changing and is part of the page content (vs design).

**2)** You can't use unicode in CSS the same way you do in HTML. You need a backslash before the number (see [Placing Unicode character in CSS content value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393462/placing-unicode-character-in-css-content-value))

Now, on to the answer to your main question...

**Option 1**:
If you want the CSS content value to always be the same, you can use CSS pseudo elements `::after` and/or `::before` to accomplish what you were trying to do (see snippet below). You can't use content in CSS without these, though.

```css
.cart-item-link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: transparent !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.cart-item-link:hover::before {
  content: "Add to Cart";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 230, 230, 0.5);
  min-width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="/?preview_id=4212&preview_nonce=a62d30b2b8&preview=true&add-to-cart=5767" class="cart-item-link">
  <img src="http://neuronade.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/Shop-Produktbild_Bundle_englisch-min-mhvx28jvtfhpc0dhkugvgrvgvg1h17l9ze3zkr118a.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

**Option 2**:
Of course, there is another possibility, too: The "add to cart" could also be placed into a `<span>` tag which could then use CSS with a slightly different selector like `.cart-item-link:hover > .cart-item-info { ... }`. (see snippet below)

```css
.cart-item-link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: transparent !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.cart-item-link > .cart-item-info {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 230, 230, 0.5);
  min-width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cart-item-link:hover > .cart-item-info {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="/?preview_id=4212&preview_nonce=a62d30b2b8&preview=true&add-to-cart=5767" class="cart-item-link">
  <span class="cart-item-info">Add to Cart</span>
  <img src="http://neuronade.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/Shop-Produktbild_Bundle_englisch-min-mhvx28jvtfhpc0dhkugvgrvgvg1h17l9ze3zkr118a.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly..you want a hand on hover?...then you use

cursor:pointer

```
a.hunderter:hover {
    background-color: rgba(100,230,230,0.5);
    background-position: 0 0;
    content:"&#9205; &#10145;Zum Warenkorb hinzufügen";
    cursor:pointer
}
```

```css
.shop_bar{
background:black;
  color:white;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}
.product_img:hover .shop_bar{
opacity:1;
}

Edit: The approach below shows how to add a bar at the bottom of the product...when you hover over the image the bard with some details will show..put whatever details you want in this html tag.
```

```html
<div class="product_img">
  <img src="https://spacewallet.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/businessblack-1-ohne-Rand.jpg">
  <div class="shop_bar">
    Buy this
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but actually I am trying the following:
There is an Image (shop-product) and when it is hovered, I would like to get a effect like in this website: https://spacewallet.de/shop

But my Code doesnt work and does not show any image

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem with adding a `<span>`, that is only visible on hover:

```css
.hunderter {
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/200/300);
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.hunderter span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
a.hunderter:hover span {
  background-color: rgba(100, 230, 230, 0.5);
  visibility: visible;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hunderter">
  <span>&#9205; &#10145;Zum Warenkorb hinzufügen</span>
</a>
```