# Correct way to get custom template directory

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a custom template that includes a specific folder where the CSS files are located:

```
WP\wp-content\themes\tema\css
```

It does not find the file when I add it to my HTML file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/tema/css/style.css">
```

I came across `get_template_directory()` but I don't know how to implement this so that I can access to my template folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to point out here is that [`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) returns an absolute path instead of a URL.

Instead you will need to make use of either [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) or [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/).

Your example would then look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css">
```

The second thing to address is **how** you are adding your stylesheet. Wordpress has a very useful function that is optimised for adding stylesheets called: [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

Instead of manually adding your stylesheet to the `header.php` inside your theme directory, you can instead add it inside your `functions.php` file, like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_my_custom_scripts' );
function so_my_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), '20180618' );
}
```

Comment: I dont have a fucntions.php in my custom theme, where should i download the "starter pack for custom templates" ? :)

Comment: My personal preference for a barebones theme is [_s (underscores)](http://underscores.me/) - an alternative is to create a [custom plugin to enqueue your custom stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50832019/6049581) although that route is most definitely overkill if you are already building your own theme.

Comment: Because it's a roundabout way to do something that can easily be achieved inside your own functions.php file :) nothing wrong with it though, just personal preference :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this inside your `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'st', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', '', '0.0.1', 'all' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try tilde `~` to come to main root of website like this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/wp-content/themes/tema/css/style.css">
```