# Refactoring special HTML characters

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

```
<li class="retro-font">Newsletters&nbsp;&loz;&nbsp;</li>
```

I have the above code designed to create a space and a diamond after each section.  It's a retro look style choice.
I'd like to not have to repeat `&nbsp;&loz;&nbsp;` after each and every element.  Is there a way to extract that into a method or a class or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can add a pseudo element after each `.retro-font` element, containing the diamond [ASCII](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25ca/index.htm) code.

```css
.retro-font:after {
  content: "\25ca";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="retro-font">Newsletters</li>
  <li class="retro-font">Oldletters</li>
</ul>
```

[Placing Unicode character in CSS content value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393462/placing-unicode-character-in-css-content-value)

Comment: You are the real MVP. This is exactly the functionality I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

The CSS answer that @dw_ gives is a good one. But if, for whatever reason, you prefer to create the effect with Rails rather than CSS, you could use a helper. In a helper module:

```
def diamond_li(string)
  '<li class="retro-font">' + string + '&nbsp;&loz;&nbsp;</li>'
end
```

In you view:

```
<%= diamond_li("Newsletters") %>
```