# Weird <li> behavior

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have this website I'm working on:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10264776/Web%20sustn.sk/odbory/fotograficky_dizajn.html

For some reason right of this box (Ctrl+F 1992) presents a weird behavior where the content of the li is pushed by few pixels, it's not is the styles, they're same for all of them, however I noticed that it's the only ul that doesn't have it's content push from one line to another like the others in the table do.

Any ideas how to fix this? All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to comment  on style.css line 119

```
.list {
    border-color: #BBBBBB;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    /*width: 560px;*/
}
```

By doing this your problem will solve only for that element but your width will remove from entire elements where .list is applied so you need to tweak on that particular table where 1992 is mention. It is table behavior it expands the table cells as per the text and layout or breathing space. So you need to put the width on that particular table cells.

Comment: Cheers! Thanks for taking time to look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
.list ul li
{
list-style: none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
padding-left: 1em; 
text-indent: -.7em;
}

li:before 
{
content: "• ";
color: red; /* or whatever color you prefer */
}
```

for a detailed explanation look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/how-to-define-the-color-of-bullets-in-ul-li-lists-via-css-without-using-any-im/5308785#comment18326651_5308785)