# Changing the color of a bullet in a list?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with changing the color of a bullet in a list.

So I have a list inside a `<nav>` tag in my HTML file:

```html
<nav id="top-menu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="">Home</a> </li>
        <li><span> <a href="">Products</a> </span></li>
        <li> <a href="">Statistics</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Countries</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Settings</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="">Contacts</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

So as you can see my `<nav>` tag has an `id="top-menu"`. And one more thing:

```
<li><span> <a href="">Products</a> </span></li>
```

Here you can see that I put a `<span>` tag inside my bullet.

Here is my CSS file:

```css
nav#top-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33px;
    background-color: #696969;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#top-menu ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#top-menu ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then I add this:

```css
#top-menu ul li span {
    color: black;
}
```

The problem is it doesn't change anything.

In other words for now every bullet in my navigation menu is white but I want to make "Products" black.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/tWGge/) to play with

Comment: `<li>`s add their bullets on their outside left border. Changing the color of a `<span>` *inside* the `<li>` will do nothing to the bullet; the `<span>` contains only the "Products" link.

Comment: Why not simply add a class to teh specific `li` you want to change properties for?

Comment: do you add a span-tag to mark it as active? in this case you might set a class  like <li class="active">...</li>
to access it via css use a 'dot' like #top-menu ul li.active

Comment: Check the list of bullet types on [MDN `list-style-type` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type). You could apply a class to the selected `<li>`, then change the `list-style-type` from `none` to `disc`, a black circle, or `square`, a black square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to style bullets you could try doing:

```
    ul { list-style: none; }

    li:before { content:"\2022 \00A0"; color: blue; }
```

### [DEMO](http://zekefranco.me/demos/bullets/)

Answer (score 4):

how about this post: [How to set Bullet colors in UL/LI html lists via CSS without using any images or span tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/how-to-define-the-color-of-bullets-in-ul-li-lists-via-css-without-using-any-im?rq=1)
excerpt:

```css
li:before {
    content: "• ";
    color: red; 
}
```

in your case

```css
#top-menu ul li span:before {
    content: "• ";
    color: black; 
}
#top-menu ul li:before {
    content: "• ";
    color: someOtherColor; 
}
```

Update: adding a fiddle with red dots and a single black one, so you can easily switch the active one
[red/black demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EMpUk/2)
I'm using a class to define the active item

```
#top-menu ul li.active:before { content: "• "; color: black; }
#top-menu ul li:before { content: "• "; color: red; }
```