# UL List - Different coloured bullets

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the colour of each individual bullet icon (or even just use a different image on each) on a ul li element? So 1 is green, 2 is blue, 3 is yellow etc. Via CSS.

Here is my little list now, I'd like to make the bullets bigger if possible.

```
<nav class="navigation-list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/" class="active">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/About-Us" >about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Products" >products</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Contact-Us" >contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#header .navigation-list { 
    float: left; 
}
#header .navigation-list ul { 
    margin-top: 38px; 
}
#header .navigation-list ul li { 
    display: inline; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding: 0 25px; 
    font-family: newsgoth_btbold; 
    font-size: 12px; 
}
```

This is what I am after: http://tinypic.com/r/11ux6xk/8

Comment: Just add a different `color` to each li.

Comment: What Paulie_D said. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/rFW8d/1/)

Comment: You can't automatically cycle through a colour range (which I think is the intent of the question), but you can definitely assign a specific colour to the bullet of a specific list-item.

Comment: other way of above [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/rFW8d/2/). or best way is to add different classes to each li.

Comment: @Mr_Green That just seems silly. But works lol.

Comment: Also if you don't want to color the text inside, could do [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/rFW8d/4/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define the Color of Bullets in UL/LI Lists via CSS,  WITHOUT using any image bullets or any span tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/how-to-define-the-color-of-bullets-in-ul-li-lists-via-css-without-using-any-im)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul{
   list-style-type: none;
   list-style-position: outside;
   list-style-image: none;
}

li:before {
   content: "• ";
}


.navigation-list ul li:nth-child(1){
   color: red; /* or whatever color you prefer */
}

.navigation-list ul li:nth-child(2){
   color: blue; /* or whatever color you prefer */
}
```

You would need to do this for each of your list items changing the nth-child +1

Comment: Is there a way to increase the size of the bullets too?

Comment: @JordanC26 use `font-size`.

Comment: Of course, @Mr_Green has it correct. This is because you're using text to add a bullet point. You can manipulate it just like you can manipulate text within CSS. Font-size, text-decoration you name it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining a pattern like every third element will be yellow. Every second bullet will be red, then that can be achieved using **nth-child** pseudo class

```
#header .navigation-list ul li:nth-child(3n) { color:green; }
#header .navigation-list ul li:nth-child(3n+1) { color:blue; }
#header .navigation-list ul li:nth-child(3n+2) { color:yellow; }
```

If you want to implements different different color, then you need to give individual styling

Comment: This would change the colour of the paragraph too. 
You would need to change the style of the a attribute:
li a{color: #000;}

Comment: Remember that [`:nth-child` is not supported in IE8 or below](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child)