# Bullet point background color attribute? CSS

Tags: css

I'm looking to change the background colour of my bullet points,

```
ul {
 list-style-type: square;
 list-style-position: outside;
 list-style-image: none;
}
```

Is there a bullet point background colour attribute?
Somthing like this?

```
list-style-background-color: blue;
```

EDIT

```
color: blue
```

Changes the font colour and the bullet point colour, but I would like to just change the bullet point colour and leave the font alone.

Comment: No, because it's not well-defined how exactly the list marker box should be drawn, and therefore there's no way to determine how this background color will appear in your list styles. There may be workarounds but it all depends on your intended result.

Comment: Are you speaking about the color of the bullet or about the color of the background of the bullet?

Comment: The colour of the bullet and the background of the bullet are separate? I didn't know that. I guess I mean the background-color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the Color of Bullets in UL/LI Lists via CSS, WITHOUT using images or span tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/how-to-set-the-color-of-bullets-in-ul-li-lists-via-css-without-using-images-or)

Comment: Background of bullet is not the same as color of bullet. In this fiddle, background is gold and color is red : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Jv694/

Comment: +1 for teaching me summit new @web-tiki :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/4Dj99/2/)**

If you don't wish to use `<span>` or `<div>`

You can use `:before` to add custom bullet to your `li`

```
li {
    list-style:none;
}

li:before {
    content: "";
    position:relative;
    left: -10px;
    background-color:red;

    display:inline-block;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
}
```

Comment: and what if instead of bullet I want to show numbers?

Comment: @KheemaPandey you can use the counter attribute : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Jv694/1/

Comment: @KheemaPandey : of-course for that you need to use other answers and now web-tiki's comment :P, my answer for the above question only. What if I want to have a diamond bullet? or some shape bullet? in that case this would be a good option.

Comment: @web-tiki : wow! I didn't know that. Thank you so much. I want to +1 you!

Comment: @web-tiki thanks for reminding me about `counter`. Since long time didn't use it..

Answer (score 2):

try like this : **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/4Dj99/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><span>one</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>one</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>one</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>one</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: square;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-image: none;
    color:#f00;
}
li {
    color:#f00;
}
li span {
    color:#999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This http://jsfiddle.net/8dGBr/

```
<ul>
    <li><div>Hi</div></li>
    <li><div>Hi</div></li>
    <li><div>Hi</div></li>
</ul>

li{
    color:blue;
}
li div{
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just write color:blue; and add to`<p> or <span>` to inner text with color:black