# How to add a CSS background for ::marker in list?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML ordered list with a structure something like this.

```
<ol>
  <li class="myclass"> First Element
  </li>
  <li class="myclass"> First Element
  </li>
  <li class="myclass"> First Element
  </li>
</ol>
```

I wanted to add a background colour to list numbers 1,2,3. I found `::marker` selector available in CSS. But, then I was able to use this `::marker` selector to change the color of the font, but I'm unable to change the background-color.

```
.myclass::marker {
  color: red;
}
```

The background-color property doesn't seem to work inside `::marker` selector. Is there any work around?

---

Edit:

I'm looking to have a design similar to this
[numbering background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX4HY.png)

Comment: Right now, they do not: https://nimb.ws/yPdrqA You can use the pseudo-element method, instead.

Comment: A little research won't hurt https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker#allowable_properties  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428980/bullet-point-background-color-attribute-css

Comment: @MihaiT Thanks for sharing these resources. I've gone through these resources before posting. I was just looking to know if any workaround is possible to achieve.

Comment: Yes, the second link is a workaround using pseudo elements

Comment: @MihaiT I have tried the workaround shared in the second link removes all the numbering, while I've to maintain the numbering of the ordered list in addition to the background.
Workaround result: https://codepen.io/nirmal9965/pen/gOWYgwK
Expected result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX4HY.png

Comment: @NirmalKumar added an answer below

Comment: We can simple make use of the following css property: list-style-image

Answer (score 3):

Pseudo element marker works like inline text element and doesn't support property background. But instead, you can apply background for another pseudo-element, as an example ::before. It will work if you add some properties else: content, width, height, display.

```
.myclass {
    position: relative;
}
.myclass::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code snippet. I've tried it and it seems like the background is appearing over the text: https://codepen.io/nirmal9965/pen/eYWOgvp

Comment: Nothing special, position values was set conditionally, as example, not ready recipe. Because we don't know which bakground you want. Just play with this properties. You could change values, as example, left: -5px; and something else. Also, you should use tag <ul> instead <ol> for unordered lists. You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

As explain in another answer here, you can use pseudo elements to achieve what you want. In your example https://codepen.io/nirmal9965/pen/gOWYgwK you were using `list-style:none;` which ofcourse removes the numbers because it transforms the ordered list in a default list.

Just use pseudo elements and position them under the numbers. You can tweak the positioning and the height/width of the `before` pseudo-element.

```css
li {
   position:relative;
   font-size:16px;
   }
li:before {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    left:-20px;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:-1;
    display:inline-block;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    First element
  </li>
  <li>
    Second element
  </li>
</ol>
```