# Lists with coloured numbers and <strong> elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a list that has the number in a coloured circle:

![screenshot][1]

I was able to achieve this by using a :before element and a counter (something like this: [How to add a CSS background for ::marker in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68135553/how-to-add-a-css-background-for-marker-in-list)), but then discovered that this doesn't indent the second line.

So I switched to `display: flex;`, which with a few tweaks to alignment worked great (and meant the circles stayed round easier)!  Except now the many, many `<strong>` elements I need to use in the list have gone awry, which from what I can tell is Just How It Is.

I was able to get the result that I wanted by adding a `<p>` to each list item (example: `<li><p>Click on the <strong>Inbox</strong> in the global navigation.</p></li>)`, but this is clunky and will cause problems for colleagues trying to use the same kind of list but with less coding skills.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this that gets the coloured circle but also lets me use `<strong>`?  I can't just use a `<span>` with bold font as I need the semantic meaning of strong for accessibility reasons.

Edit:

Original code, where the second line of wrapped text wasn't indented:
[enter image description here][2]

```css
/*settings for whole list <ol> */
.round-number-list-b {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    counter-reset: item;
}

/*settings for list items <li> */
.round-number-list-b > li {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    counter-increment: item;
    list-style: none inside;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem
}

/*settings for actual number */
.round-number-list-b > li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5rem;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    content: counter(item);
    padding: 0.1rem;
    margin-right: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    background: #005577;
    border-radius: 5rem;
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Additions for the second iteration (the rest of the code was the same)

```css
.round-number-list > li {
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
}

.round-number-list > li:before {
flex: 0 0 1.3rem;
}
```

This is what caused problems with the `<strong>` elements
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL0io.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8vhz.png

Comment: What do you mean by *this doesn't indent the second line*? Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, this might help: [CSS Tricks: Style List Markers in CSS, by Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/style-list-markers-css/)

Comment: I've edited to added the MRE, and a screenshot of the second line wrap

Comment: it is hard to tell how your CSS works without your markup (HTML). But you should check the link to CSS Tricks article in my earlier comment

Answer (score 1):

Using the ::before selector, counter and a little bit of tweaking:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: count;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
ol li {
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  counter-increment: count;
  position: relative;
}
ol li::before {
  content: counter(count);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: .8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  --size: 23px;
  left: calc(-1 * var(--size) - 10px);
  line-height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background: #a1a;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Peaches</li>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Plums</li>
  <li><p>Click on the <strong>Inbox</strong> in the global navigation.</p></li>
</ol>
```