# Change the bullet color of list

Tags: css

I have a list,

```
    <ul class="listStyle">
        <li>
            <strong>View :</strong> blah blah.
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>Edit :</strong> blah blah blah.
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I am using square bullet for list.

```
    .listStyle{
        list-style-type: square;
    }
```

Bullets appears in black color. Is it possible change the color of the bullet? If yes, how can i change it?

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: [How to set the Color of Bullets in UL/LI Lists via CSS, WITHOUT using images or span tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/how-to-set-the-color-of-bullets-in-ul-li-lists-via-css-without-using-images-or)

Comment: add span tag before strong and assign color to span.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/juxasa/1/edit

Comment: You can use pseudo-elements ::before and then apply a content: "• "; and hide list-style.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Example JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/pw844n5x/)

Bullets take the `color` property of the list:

```
.listStyle {
    color: red;
}
```

Note if you want your list text to be a different colour, you have to wrap it in say, a `p`, for example:

```
.listStyle p {
    color: black;
}
```

[Example HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/pw844n5x/):

```
<ul class="listStyle">
    <li>
        <p><strong>View :</strong> blah blah.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p><strong>View :</strong> blah blah.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @C-linkNepal you're right, and you were writing that as I was updating my answer :)

Comment: red is working. ".listStyle p" is not working. Since content is not  inside p tag

Comment: I disagree, added a JS Fiddle to prove it.

Comment: :-) in my question, there is no p tag inside li. May b i could add a span tag or somthing to make it work. Since adding p tag will add whole lot of styles to li

Comment: I was aware you had no `p` tags. Yes you could use any other tag :)

Comment: Its better write more, smarter css once and use less tags 100 times.

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend you to use background-image instead of default list.

```
.listStyle {
    list-style: none;
    background: url(image_path.jpg) no-repeat left center;
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use background-image as bullet, there is an option to do it with pseudo element:

```
.liststyle{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.liststyle:before {
    content: "• ";
    color: red; /* or whatever color you prefer */
    font-size: 20px;/* or whatever the bullet size you prefer */
}
```

Comment: pseudo-elements is a poor choice for verbose bullets. Text will wrap under bullet as opposed to be aligned with the text line above with real bullets

Comment: Pseudo-elements are NOT a poor choice: http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/ytH5P/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use image

```
.listStyle {
    list-style: none;
    background: url(bullet.jpg) no-repeat left center;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Don't use images for circle, it can be generated using css easily. No requests and zoom support.