# Is it possible to prevent li:before from forcing a list item paragraph to the next line (JSFiddle inside)?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm using FontAwesome icons as custom bullets for my unordered lists, but using li:before seems to change the behavior of paragraph tags in list items.

See this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ko2efv7b/)** for a paragraph tag in action in two different lists. One with li:before, one without.

HTML:

```
<ul class="before">
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>
        <p>list item 2 (paragraph)</p>
        <p>list item 2 (sub paragraph)</p>
    </li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
</ul>
<br />
<br />
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>
        <p>list item 2 (paragraph)</p>
        <p>list item 2 (sub paragraph)</p>
    </li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.before li:before {
    content:"B4";
    color: red;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

How can I get list item paragraphs to appear on the same line as the li:before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being that paragraphs are block elements, they will start a new line... that is, unless you float the item in front it.  There are some other styling issues which arise from this, but I'm sure you can figure those out (I compensated for some of the issues in my example):

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/ko2efv7b/2/

```
.before li:before {
    content:"B4";
    color: red;
    margin-right: 8px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This relies on the user knowing the width of the `:before` content to properly reset padding, right?

Comment: Not really - for some reason floating the pseudo element caused the bullets to appear inside the list ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/ko2efv7b/3/)).  There may be a better solution, but I'm not going to find it for free ;)

Comment: Touché - if it were my project, I'd use the code I posted ;)  It's kind of moot anyways as the OP is actually *replacing* the bullets.  [Here's an example with different sized "bullets"](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/ko2efv7b/6/)

Comment: `list-style-image`, or this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/how-to-set-the-color-of-bullets-in-ul-li-lists-via-css-without-using-images-or

Answer (score 1):

You should probably accept Ryan's answer, but in case you want a much more hackish answer that doesn't require you to know the width of the before content, here's my attempt:

## [Fiddle with hiding dots](http://jsfiddle.net/ko2efv7b/5/)

**CSS**

```
.before li {
    list-style: dot outside none;
}
.before li:before {
    content:"B40M8UW0T?";
    color: red;
    margin-right: 8px;
    float: left;
    list-style: dot outside none;
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: white;
}
```

**[Fiddle with a green background illustrating the hack](http://jsfiddle.net/ko2efv7b/4/)**

So, basically we're telling the browser to display that `:before` pseudo to display as a list-item itself, and then hiding the resultant bullet point for the actual list item by matching the background-color of the underlying element.  In the fiddle I left the `ul` green to illustrate this happening.

It's not a perfect solution, but there won't be a perfect solution for what you're looking to do without a tremendous amount of effort.

Cheers.