# TinyMCE not change list bullet color

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

Is it possible to change bullet colors of ordered/unordered list to same as text? Example: Create new list > add some text > change font color > no color here. Screenshot:

[image]

Do I need set something, to work it properly? Like in MS Word?

PS: In online edition of Word, it works well too.

Comment: Maybe you want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/how-to-set-the-color-of-bullets-in-ul-li-lists-via-css-without-using-images-or

Comment: Problem 1 is I cannot edit TinyMCE so deep (changing main functions), problem 2 is I don't really know, how to edit it and problem 3 is my company won't provide me more time to re-edit a lot of stuff in that plugin, so I need to find out solution from TinyMCE.